# How to generate random numbers without repetition in Swift?

Tags: swift

How can I generate random numbers between 0 and 31 without call the number twice in Swift Language ?

Comment: What does it mean to "call the number"?

Comment: I mean if the random number was 5 , it doesn't repeat 5 again in the method

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function that returns a random-number generating closure, like this:

```
func randomSequenceGenerator(min: Int, max: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var numbers: [Int] = []
    return {
        if numbers.isEmpty {
            numbers = Array(min ... max)
        }

        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numbers.count)))
        return numbers.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

To use it, first call the generator once to create the random sequence generator, then call the return value as many times as you like. This will print out random values between one and six, cycling through all of them before starting over:

```
let getRandom = randomSequenceGenerator(min: 1, max: 6)
for _ in 1...20 {
    print(getRandom())
}
```

Comment: http://s17.postimg.org/pz2vbd98v/Screen_Shot_2014_10_20_at_05_26_13.png

Comment: http://s17.postimg.org/pz2vbd98v/Screen_Shot_2014_10_20_at_05_26_13.png
it does repeat the numbers I want it to be without repetitive . In fact, I have playing cards and I want them appear equally in 4 UIImages without being Duplicated all of them in one array @NateCook

Comment: It's repeating the numbers only because he's calling it more times than there were items in the array. Note, he's generating numbers 1-6 in random order, and when he generates numbers 7-12, again he's generating numbers 1-6 in random order, etc.

Comment: @Fahad Right, you'd need to modify the numbers in my example for your actual case. (Although looking again, my method doesn't account for the restart - you may a get a repeat after exhausting each sequence of values.)