# Unity array of colors prevent same value

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to generate two random colors from a single array which are supposed not to be same. One of the colors is the bg color of the label, the other one is the text color of the text on top of it. But curiously i fail. Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ColorText : MonoBehaviour {
public GUISkin mySkin;
public GameObject obj;
private Color clr;
private Color txtClr;
private string clrName;

Color[] colorList = new Color[13]{
    new Color(0,0,255,255), // mavi
    new Color(165,42,42,255), // kahverengi
    new Color(192,192,192,255), // gri (192,192,192 gümüş)
    new Color(0,128,0,255), // yeşil
    new Color(128,0,0,255), // bordo
    new Color(255,165,0,255), // turuncu
    new Color(255,192,203,255), // pembe
    new Color(128,0,128,255), // mor
    new Color(255,0,0,255), // kırmızı
    new Color(64,224,208,255), // turkuaz
    new Color(255,255,0,255), // sarı
    new Color(255,255,255,255), // beyaz
    new Color(0,0,0,255), // siyah
};

string[] colorNames = new string[13]{
    "Mavi",
    "Kahverengi",
    "Gri", // gri (192,192,192 gümüş)
    "Yeşil", // yeşil
    "Bordo", // bordo
    "Turuncu", // turuncu
    "Pembe", // pembe
    "Mor", // mor
    "Kırmızı", // kırmızı
    "Turkuaz", // turkuaz
    "Sarı", // sarı
    "Beyaz", // beyaz
    "Siyah", // siyah
};

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating ("changeColors", 0, 1f);
}

void changeColors(){
    int a, b;
    a = (int)Random.Range (0, colorList.Length);
    b = (int)Random.Range (0, colorList.Length);

    if (a == b) {
        do{
            a = (int)Random.Range (0, colorList.Length);
            b = (int)Random.Range (0, colorList.Length);
        }while(a == b);
        clr = colorList [a];
        txtClr = colorList [b];
        clrName = colorNames [Random.Range (0, colorNames.Length)];

    } else {
        clr = colorList [a];
        txtClr = colorList [b];
        clrName = colorNames [Random.Range (0, colorNames.Length)];
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnGUI() {
    GUI.skin = mySkin;
    mySkin.box.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
    mySkin.box.normal.textColor = txtClr;
    //GUI.backgroundColor = Color.blue;

    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    //Set new texture as background
    mySkin.box.normal.background = texture;
    //Set the texture color
    texture.SetPixel(1,1,clr);
    // Apply all SetPixel calls
    texture.Apply();

    /*float scalex = (float)(Screen.width) / 480.0f;
    float scaley = (float)(Screen.height) / 800.0f;
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(scalex, scaley, 1));*/


    GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width/2 - 400,10,800,200), clrName, "box");
    //GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/2, 15, 100, 20), "Hello World!");
}
```

}

Any spotted point of i've been missing? Thanks for your help in advance.
Edit: I checked the indices to compare. They aren't same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1)

Comment: It's not. I checked the indices. They aren't same.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly less efficient way for you to do this. First clone your array of colors to a temporary list that you can change however you want. Then remove the index of the first random color. Here is an example:

```
void changeColors()
{
    List<Color> tempColors = new List<Color>(colorList);

    // Get the first random index.
    int a = (int)Random.Range (0, tempColors.Length);  
    // Assign the colour.
    clr = tempColors[a];  
    // Remove the colour from the list so that it is impossible to select the same again.
    tempColors.RemoveAt(a); 
    // Get second index.
    int b = (int)Random.Range (0, tempColors.Length); 
    // Assign second colour.
    txtClr = tempColors[b];   
}
```

I hope this can help you.

EDIT:
If the problem turns out to be something else I think a code cleanup is appropriate here. Just to show you a different way of writing:

```
void changeColors(){
    int a,b;
    a = b = 0;

    while (a == b) 
    {
        a = (int)Random.Range (0, colorList.Length);
        b = (int)Random.Range (0, colorList.Length);
    }

    clr = colorList [a];
    txtClr = colorList [b];
    clrName = colorNames [Random.Range (0, colorNames.Length)];
}
```

This should do exactly the same as your current code if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Good point. I'll give it a try when i'm available. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I tried exactly the same code as in your edit but something else must be wrong because it didn't work as expected. Anyway, i'll try your first code then inform you.

Comment: I checked the code but the issue still remains. As by far i could realize, only colors red and white causing problem.

Comment: What weird behaviour. Maybe add some code to call your function on a key press to eliminate timing issues.

Comment: What i'm mostly suspicious of is a timing issue. But i can't come up with a proper solution about it.

Comment: What i recently realized is even though i commented out the white rgb color code in the list colorList, it kept setting backgroun color to white. Any ideas why so?

Comment: I wonder.. I'm not sure but what if you put the values from 0 - 1 instead of 0 - 255?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you putted it in `invokerepeating` if you only need two colors only one time and as a side note for `invokerepeating` start time don't put zero if you want it to start right away put a small value in start time

```
 void Start () {
    Changecolors();
}
```

Comment: Because the colors have to keep changing by the time.

Comment: Did you changer the invoke starting time to something more than zero

Comment: And one second isn't enough time for seeing the result make the invoke repeating time more than one

Answer (score 0):

"Color uses float values between 0 and 1, Color32 uses byte values between 0 and 255.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html

[Answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/978889/cant-prevent-same-color-random-generation.html)

alucardj solved it.