# Sequence of random numbers without repeats

Tags: java

I am trying to do a pvp event in my game server which uses 3 zones to do it randomly. I use the following code but always is returning me the values 1 and 2 and repeated as well. I need some sequence like this for example: 3-2-1-2-1-3 or something that never repeats the same number.

```
int random = Rnd.get(1, 3);

if (random == 1)
{
    setstartedpvpzone1(true);
}

if (random == 2)
{
    setstartedpvpzone2(true);
}

if (random == 3)
{
    setstartedpvpzone3(true);
}
```

this is what i get in rnd:

```
public final class Rnd
{
    /**
     * This class extends {@link java.util.Random} but do not compare and store atomically.<br>
     * Instead it`s using a simple volatile flag to ensure reading and storing the whole 64bit seed chunk.<br>
     * This implementation is much faster on parallel access, but may generate the same seed for 2 threads.
     * @author Forsaiken
     * @see java.util.Random
     */
    public static final class NonAtomicRandom extends Random
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private volatile long _seed;

        public NonAtomicRandom()
        {
            this(++SEED_UNIQUIFIER + System.nanoTime());
        }

        public NonAtomicRandom(final long seed)
        {
            setSeed(seed);
        }

        @Override
        public final int next(final int bits)
        {
            return (int) ((_seed = ((_seed * MULTIPLIER) + ADDEND) & MASK) >>> (48 - bits));
        }

        @Override
        public final void setSeed(final long seed)
        {
            _seed = (seed ^ MULTIPLIER) & MASK;
        }
    }
```

and rnd.get:

```
/**
 * Gets a random integer number from min(inclusive) to max(inclusive)
 * @param min The minimum value
 * @param max The maximum value
 * @return A random integer number from min to max
 */
public static final int get(final int min, final int max)
{
    return rnd.get(min, max);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1)

Comment: What random number library is `Rnd`? That doesn't appear to be the Java standard `Random` library. Anyway, I suspect that the the end value you pass to `get` is **exclusive** so that `get(1, 3)` means get me a value greater than or equal to 1 but **strictly less than** 3. If so, changing to `get(1, 4)` should do the trick.

Comment: Please define *"never repeats the same number"* given that your example of `3-2-1-2-1-3` shows repeats of all three numbers. Did you mean that it should run a full sequence of non-repeating numbers before starting over? Or did you mean that the same number is not allowed to come up right next to each other? Or something else?

Comment: i need only one number every time from 1 2 or 3, because i use this number to start the event random and never must be duplicated 2 times simultaneous. the number 1 correspond to the zone 1, number 2 zone 2 , number 3 zone 3, then i need new zone every time the event start.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are looking for is a random number that doesn't equal the previous one returned then the solution is much simpler:

```
private Random random = new Random();
private int previousZone = 0;

public int nextZone() {
    int zone;
    do {
        zone = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
    } while (zone == previousZone);

    previousZone = zone; //store last "generated" zone

    return zone;
}
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer, your code return me 0, no worked.

Answer (score 0):

This code never repeats any numbers, for example if you have 1,2,3 you can get a random sequence of 4 numbers, example 2,1,3.

Create an array with all numbers you need...

```
   int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
```

Then select random items

```
   for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
       int random = Rnd.get(0, a.length);
       //remove the selected item from the array
       ArrayUtils.removeElement(a, random);

       if (random == 1) {
            setstartedpvpzone1(true);
       } else if (random == 2) {
            setstartedpvpzone2(true);
       } else if (random == 3) {
            setstartedpvpzone3(true);
       }
    }
```

Comment: i am getting error in this line ArrayUtils.removeElement(a, random) the error says: the method removeElement(int[], int) is undefined for the type Arrayutils

Comment: i can use that from my sources ArrayUtils.remove(array, value) but dont match with your code. thanks for your help..

Comment: error: the method remove(T[],T) in the type Arrayutils is not aplicable for the arguments (int[],int)

Comment: as i see in javadocs removeElement is the right way http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html

Comment: yes you are right was fine, the problem was my mistake with a wrong import, but your code is returning me a secuence like this: 2-3-2-1-3-2-3-3-3-3-2-1-2-3-3-1-1, anyway thanks for try to help me, for some reason sometimes repeat the 3 lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

[not tested] It is possible that it may contain  some syntax errors as I am not a Java programmer.

```
    int a=0,b=0;
    while(true)
   {
        int random = Rnd.get(1, 3);
        if(!(a==random or b==random))
        {
            a=b;
            b=random;
            break;
        }
   }

if (random == 1)
{
    setstartedpvpzone1(true);
}

if (random == 2)
{
    setstartedpvpzone2(true);
}

if (random == 3)
{
    setstartedpvpzone3(true);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help guys..im testing your code now.

Comment: hello i tested your code and it return secuence of numbers like this: 3-2-2-3-1-2-2-1-3-2-1-2-2 always repeat the number 2, then is not valid because is repeating the numbers, anyway thanks for try to help me.

Comment: may be  it code  in an function which you call again and again which cause value of a and b assign zero each time; a and b must global variable

Answer (score 0):

Your problem boils down to a [graph](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/45graph/) traversal in which from each current zone, you only have 2 possible next zones and those choices never change. So here is how I would implement it:

```
public static class EventLocator{
    private int currentZone;
    private Random random;
    private Map<Integer, int[]> locations;
    private static EventLocator instance;

    private EventLocator() {
    }

    public static EventLocator getInstance(){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new EventLocator();
        }
        return instance;

    }

    public int getNextZone(){
        if (this.currentZone == 0) {//first time called
            this.random = new Random();
            this.locations = new HashMap<>(3);//graph <currentZone, posibleZones>
            this.locations.put(1, new int[] { 2, 3 });
            this.locations.put(2, new int[] { 1, 3 });
            this.locations.put(3, new int[] { 1, 2 });

            this.currentZone = this.random.nextInt(3) + 1;// to 1-based Zones
            return currentZone;
        }
        int[] possibleZones = this.locations.get(this.currentZone);
        int randomIndex = this.random.nextInt(2);//0 or 1 index
        this.currentZone = possibleZones[randomIndex];
        return this.currentZone;
    }
}
```

You would call it like:

```
EventLocator eventLocator = MyProgram.EventLocator.getInstance();
System.out.println(eventLocator.getNextZone());
System.out.println(eventLocator.getNextZone());
```

Comment: hello tested and this class return me a number different to 1 - 2 - 3 because no worked, thanks for your help guys, i still trying to fix it , just 3 fu cking random number and cant do it xD

Comment: a secuence of numbers like 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3 is valid too

Comment: the getNextZone() will return any zone (1,2 or 3), with no repetition. It is totally random.

Comment: EventLocator eventLocator = EventLocator.getInstance();
    
    if (eventLocator.getNextZone() == 1)
    {
     setstartedpvpzone1(true);
    }
    
    if (eventLocator.getNextZone() == 2)
    {
     setstartedpvpzone2(true);
    }
    
    if (eventLocator.getNextZone() == 3)
    {
     setstartedpvpzone3(true);
    }   i used like this and sometimes return a number between 123 but sometimes no, then the system dont work.

Comment: Call EventLocator.getInstance().getNextZone() once, like
int nextZone = EventLocator.getInstance().getNextZone();
if(nextZone==1){
...}ELSE if(nextZone==2){
...}ELSE{
...}

Comment: hello thanks for your explanation , but dont worked, return me some number that is not 1 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 private boolean _lastevent1 = false;
 
 public boolean lastevent1()
 {
  
  return _lastevent1;
 }
 
 public void setlastevent1(boolean val)
 {
  _lastevent1 = val;
 }
 
 private boolean _lastevent2 = false;
 
 public boolean lastevent2()
 {
  
  return _lastevent2;
 }
 
 public void setlastevent2(boolean val)
 {
  _lastevent2 = val;
 }
 
 private boolean _lastevent3 = false;
 
 public boolean lastevent3()
 {
  
  return _lastevent3;
 }
 
 public void setlastevent3(boolean val)
 {
  _lastevent3 = val;
 }
```

```html
    if (!lastevent1())
    {
     setlastevent3(false);
     setstartedpvpzone3(false);
     
     setstartedpvpzone1(true);
     setlastevent1(true);
    }
    
    else if (!lastevent2())
    {
     setstartedpvpzone1(false);
     setstartedpvpzone2(true);
     setlastevent2(true);
    }
    
    else if (!lastevent3())
    {
     setlastevent1(false);
     setlastevent2(false);
     
     setstartedpvpzone2(false);
     setstartedpvpzone3(true);
     setlastevent3(true);
    }
```

hello finally i fixed using booleans and i get this secuence, 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3 , i breaked my mind with it because is very confuse this code but it work now as a charm , thanks for all to try to help me i very appreciate it, great community.