# Function to generate pseudo ramdom sequence

Tags: random, generator

Lets assume an ordered finite sequence of integers `A = {0,1,2, ... k}`.
Im looking for a (seeded) function `f: A -> A` where the image of `f` seems to be ramdom, but every element is hit exactly once (bijective).

It's importatant that someone who has access to some results of `f` should neither be able to estimate if he's looking at direkt neighbours `f(n), f(n+1)` nor should he be able to guess the next result.

One idea would be to map a `range(1, k)` on a `shuffle(range(1, k))`. But this seems very low in performance (for large `k`) and does miss the basic idea of a generator. The first element in the sequece should be as expensive to calculate as the `n`-th element.

#### Difference to 'normal' randomgenerators

Read carefully before marking as dublicated. I'm not looking for randomly picking from a range where collisions are possible. Also I want to calculate the `n`-th element without calculating all `n-1`elements before, like I would have to using the MT or Xorshift.

Comment: I dont think so. Randomly picking from an almost infinite amount of numbers is not bijective (there might and will be collisions). Calling `mt_rand(1,10)`  ten times does not create a shuffled sequence of elements 1 to 10.

Comment: If your adversary has access to your results, he can always guess your last result.

Comment: @Bergi I said access to _some_, not _all_ results. This function must not be absolute random. It should just be difficult to estimate.

Comment: Sounds like a possible duplicate of [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/196017/1048572)?

Comment: Read carefully: write some code and post it here.

Comment: @Bergi Yes you are right. But the presented solutions use counter and pregenerated ranges. May be there is no solution.

Comment: @nicomp Code is just a tool. Don't you think I might implement a mathematical solution in any kind of language?

Comment: @Inceddy: There are more answer than that which pre-generates the sequence…

Comment: http://openpatent.blogspot.de/2013/04/xincrol-unique-and-random-number.html looks good on first sight.