# How to generate long (up to 25 millions) random sequence of integers in C (with no repetition)?

Tags: c, arrays, random

I need to generate long (pseudo)random arrays (1000-25 000 000 integers) where no element is repeated. How do I do it since `rand()` function does not generate numbers long enough?

I tried to use this idea: `array[i] = (rand() << 14) | rand() % length;` however I suppose there is much better way that I don't know.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A value of 1000 or 25,000,000 or 42 does not change the answer much.  For a starting point, See http://stackoverflow.com/a/196065/2410359 and [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle)

Comment: If the the array was `n=1000`, is it OK for the "no element is repeated" values to range from 0 to 999, or do you need a different range?

Comment: What is `RAND_MAX` on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for this.

Create an array of `n` elements and populate each element sequentially.

```
-------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
-------------------------
```

In this example `n` is 6.  Now select a random index from 0 to n-1 (i.e.  `rand() % n`) and swap the number at that index with the number at the top of the array.  Let's say the random index is 2.  So we swap the value at index 2 (3) and the one at n-1 (6).  Now we have:

```
                      v
-------------------------
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 3 |
-------------------------
```

Now we do the same, this time with the upper bound of the index being n-2.  Then we swap the value at that index with the value at index n-2.  Let's say time we randomly get 0.  So we swap index 0 (1) with index n-2 (5):

```
                  v
-------------------------
| 5 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
-------------------------
```

Then repeat.  Let's say the next random index is 3.  This happens to be our upper limit, so no change:

```
              v
-------------------------
| 5 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
-------------------------
```

Next we get 0:

```
          v
-------------------------
| 6 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
-------------------------
```

And finally 1:

```
      v
-------------------------
| 6 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
-------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Then I suppose I should generate an array containing values from 1 up to n (n is from 1000 up to 25 000 000) and shuffle it. The problem I still see is to generate a random number up to 25 000 000 since `RAND_MAX` on my system is 32767.

Comment: @Allemis In that case you'll need to call `rand()` twice and shift/OR, i.e. `((rand() << 15) | rand()) % length`