# Generate a collection for which newly added elements depend on the ones already added

Tags: scala

I want to create a set of randomly selected indices from an input collection `observations`:

```
case class Observation(id: Long, metric1: Double)

val observations: Seq[Observation]

val NumSamples = 100
val indices = // A set of randomly selected indices of the observations
              // WITHOUT replacement
```

The complication is that to avoid replacement of the existing indices when selecting new ones (via `myRandom.nextInt(observations.length`) we need to have *access* to the prior ones - which is afaik not possible during the initial generation of a sequence.

An outline of what I'm looking for is shown here

*Most preferred* (but I doubt it can be done..)

```
val sampledIndices: Seq[Int] = for (randInd <- 0 until NSamples) yield {
    // some random non-repeated index in [0..length(observations)]
}
```

But following is a *second choice*:

```
val randomIndices = mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]()
for (randInd <- 0 until NSamples) {
   randomIndices ++= // some random non-repeated index in
}
```

What to avoid:  multiple `var`s .. which is what I am running into so far.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1

Comment: Thx for that link: i should be using the `knuth shuffle` algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want

```
val sampledIndices: Seq[Int] = scala.util.Random.shuffle((0 until observations.size))
```

Comment: That is perfect for the particular use case ;) - and thus upvoting.  I am hoping for even more: a general solution to this kind of problem - which bugs me from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using an unfold function, which creates a Stream by creating a value and a state to get the next value in each step

```
def unfold[A,S](z: S)(implicit f: S => Option[(A,S)]): Stream[A] = {
  f(z) match{
    case None => Stream[A]()
    case Some((value, state)) => value#::unfold(state)
  }
}
```

Then to create your list:

```
unfold(Random)((a => Some(a.nextInt, a))).take(NSamples).toList
```

Comment: Why is `f` implicit?

Comment: To avoid sending it again in the recursive call:


    case Some((value, state)) => value#::unfold(state)(f)

Comment: Really? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I just noticed the `#::unfold`. That is completely new to me and going to google it

Comment: Can you explain how this avoids repeating indices?

Comment: It's an operand to append a element to a Stream

You can check the API here https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html

Comment: So my point is this is a nice template but does not actually answer the OP precisely . In addition the `NSamples` is not respected for the limits of the values returned by `scala.util.Random` (vs the `java.util.Random as requested). I am trying to fix these quibbles now. Hold on.

Comment: OK here's the fixes;  `val rand = new java.util.Random() ; unfold(rand)((a => Some(a.nextInt(NSamples), a))).take(NSamples).toList` . Actually .. this *still* does not take care of *without replacement* concerns - which is the major point of the question. So this is helpful but not an actual answer.