# How to generate random numbers without including a set number?

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to generate 8 random numbers from 1 to 25. My issue is that I already have a variable and its value is 14, with that being said my question is how to generate random numbers from 1 to 25 and if one them is equal to 14 then replace it with another random number? at the end, I want to have 8 random numbers in my array and I don't want to include 14 in it. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or how to make this more accurate? and sometimes I only end up with 7 elements in my array, does anyone knows why?

Here's my code:

```js
var arr = [];
var currentvar = 14;
 for(var i = 0 ; i < 9; i++){
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*25) + 1;
  if(num === currentvar){
     num = Math.floor(Math.random()*25) + 1;
  }else{
    arr.push(num);
  }
 }

 console.log(arr);
```

Comment: And you don't care you may have other duplicate values?

Comment: @Kaiido yes I don't want duplicate numbers in my array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Study the logic you've implemented more closely. You go through the loop exactly 9 times (not 8), and you have mutually exclusive outcomes for each iteration due to an `if...else` control flow.

*Either* you reassign `num` if it's equal to `currentvar` (which you should do correctly by removing `var` from the second assignment), *or* you add it to the array, never both in one iteration. That's what `else` means, and you probably want a `do...while` loop to assign `num` *until* it is not equal to `currentvar`.

```js
var arr = [];
var currentvar = 14;
var num;

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  do {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1;
  } while (num === currentvar);

  arr.push(num);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your `if...else` statement, you can decrement the loop counter `i` instead to repeat the loop an extra time when `num === currentvar`:

```js
var arr = [];
var currentvar = 14;

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 1;

  if (num === currentvar) {
    i--;
  } else {
    arr.push(num);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @progx there are plenty of [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196017/1541563) regarding generating unique random values in a given range of numbers. I would like to point out that this is not what you originally asked.