# Algorithm or formula that can take an incrementing counter and make it appear uniquely random

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, integer, formula

I am wondering if there is a general formula of some sort that can take a single incrementing integer, and run it through a modulus sort of thing to shift it to a random place, so as you increment the counter, its output value jumps around and appears random, yet no value is ever hit twice. Assuming some limit on the set of numbers like 16-bit integers (65536 integers), or 32-bit integers, etc.. Perhaps there is a way to spiral numbers down somehow, I don't know. The sequence would be predictable, but to a layman it would appear random without thinking much of it.

For example, you can multiply a number by 2 to make it not appear directly incremented. But that's not very sophisticated. You could perhaps start the number at the middle of the set (like 30103 for 16-bit integers), then multiply by 2 and rotate the numbers using a modulus, and this would appear even less incremented. But you could still see a pattern.

I'm wondering what sorts of patterns or equations you could run an incremented number through (in a bounded set of integers) so that the output appears the least predictable as possible, and at the same time it never hits the same number twice. This way you could make IDs appear randomly generated to the layman without having to store all the IDs in a database in random order in advance. The formula would generate them from a single stored integer. What is possible in this regard, and what is the equation? How far can it theoretically go?

Maybe you could make the set odd, and skip every 20th number, and somehow prove that it will eventually revolve through the whole set without repeats. I can't figure this out though.

Update: This seems to be in the field of [pseudorandom number generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators), like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-based_random_number_generator_(CBRNG)#Squares_RNG), but I'm not sure if they fit the added constraint of never repeating the number.

[Here](https://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/) is what I found and implemented, but it's giving some duplicates :/.

```js
const fetch = (x, o) => {
  if (x >= o) {
    return x
  } else {
    const v = (x * x) % o
    return (x <= o / 2) ? v : o - v
  }
}

const fetch32 = (x) => fetch(x, 4294967291)
const fetch16 = (x) => fetch(x, 65519)
const fetch8 = (x) => fetch(x, 251)

// the last number can be anything.
const build32 = (x, o) => fetch32((fetch32(x) + o) ^ 1542469173)
const build16 = (x, o) => fetch16((fetch16(x) + o) ^ 42703)
const build8 = (x, o) => fetch8((fetch8(x) + o) ^ 101)

let i = 0
let n = Math.pow(2, 32)
while (i < n) {
  let j = 0
  let r = {}
  while (j < n) {
    let x = build32(j, i)
    if (r[x]) throw `${i}:${j}:${x}`
    r[x] = true
    j++
  }
  i++
}
```

The other linked question in the comment doesn't show a JavaScript implementation that adheres the the uniqueness constraint.

Comment: You mean like a hashing function?

Comment: [Linear congruential generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) might do for your case.

Comment: @ScottSauyet how can you tell if they follow the uniqueness constraint?

Comment: Also, hash tables may have [astronomically unlikely collisions](https://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/), but I would like to have absolutely no collisions whatsoever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1)

Comment: @PeterO. no I don't think so, not directly, and they don't seem to obey the uniqueness constraint.

Comment: You encrypt the counter and interpret the resulting bits as a number.  The ability to decrypt back to the counter proves that there are not going to be any duplicates.

Comment: @MattTimmermans why am I getting duplicates in the example I showed?

Comment: I didn't check your work too closely, but x*x will certainly lose low-order bits in some cases, because javascript only gives you 56 bits of precision.

Comment: Awesome, I think you might be right. I changed it to a 28-bit implementation and it seems to work.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982102/how-to-prove-these-pseudo-random-number-generators-dont-repeat-until-running-th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a sequence, where one value is produced from knowing what the previous value was, then what you are looking for could be a [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), with a modulus of a power of 2. There are a few parameters involved:

- *m*: the modulus, which in your case is 2<sup>8</sup>, 2<sup>16</sup>, or 2<sup>32</sup>.
- *a*: the multiplier. To ensure that all values are produced before the first duplicate is generated, this must be a multiple of 4 plus 1 (assuming *m* is a power of 2).
- *c*: the increment. It must be odd.

You can play with these numbers to arrive at a series that you are satisfied with in terms of "randomness".

The above referenced Wikipedia article lists some parameter choices that are used in some pseudo random generators. I have just selected *a=97* and *c* some odd number half way the range.

Here is some code to prove the uniqueness:

```js
/*
    Assuming that m is a power of 2:
    - c must be odd
    - a % 4 must be 1
*/
function createFetch(m, a, c) { // Returns a function
     return x => (a * x + c) % m;
}
const m = 2**16;
const fetch16 = createFetch(m, 97, (m>>1)-1);

const r = new Set;
let x = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    x = fetch16(x);
    if (i < 10) console.log(x);
    if (r.has(x)) throw `${i}:${x}`
    r.add(x);
}
console.log("...");
console.log(`generated ${r.size} unique numbers`);
```

NB/ this is a good use case for a generator, which in JavaScript looks like this:

```js
function * fetch(m, a, c, x=1) {
     while (true) {
         x = (a * x + c) % m;
         yield x;
     }
}
const m = 2**16;
const fetch16 = fetch(m, 97, (m>>1)-1);

const r = new Set;
for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    x = fetch16.next().value;
    if (i < 10) console.log(x);
    if (r.has(x)) throw `${i}:${x}`
    r.add(x);
}
console.log("...");
console.log(`generated ${r.size} unique numbers`);
```

Comment: Wonderful! Does this run into the problem on squaring 32-bit integers where they might lose precision and thus have a duplicate on the 32-bit case? 16 and 8-bit case I'm not worried about.

Comment: This will indeed produce intermediate values that will overflow the value of *m*. Two comments about that: (1) In JavaScript that is not an issue, as there are 53 bits available in its internal float representation. (2) In a system that uses 32-bit typed ints, and where a product will just result in the modulo result, this will not be a problem either, as that just means you do `((a * x) % m + c) % m` which is equivalent to the expression in the code.

Comment: How do you adapt this for random 8-bit values? Because you call this `fetch32` but are doing `2**16`, so not sure.

Comment: That was a misnomer. I should call it `fetch16` (corrected). For 8-bit you would do `m=2**8` and call the function `fetch8`.

Answer (score 1):

Any block cipher whose block size is n bits is a permutation of {0,1,2, ..., 2<sup>n</sup>-1}. Thus, if E is such a block cipher and k is a valid key for E, then E<sub>k</sub>(0), E<sub>k</sub>(1), ..., E<sub>k</sub>(2<sup>n</sup>-1) are all distinct. If the block cipher is good then the values appear "random" to the naked eye. If you change the key k you get a different permutation.

This is actually mentioned in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-based_random_number_generator_(CBRNG)#CBRNGs_based_on_block_ciphers) you provided.

Consider [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/53246/676) answer as well.

Comment: Can you show how it is implemented in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var bottomLimit = 1
var topLimit = 10
var arr = []
for (var i = bottomLimit; i < topLimit; i++) {
  arr.push(i)
}
arr = shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array#answer-2450976
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Comment: If it uses `Math.random()` then you have to precompute all the values in advance and make sure they are all unique, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Nope - they're all unique. This is the Fisher–Yates shuffle - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: To explain what this does in detail, it takes the last element and switches it with another random element. Then it takes the next last element, and switches it with another random element, and so on, all the way to the end.

Comment: The values will be unique, but the downside is that you need to first allocate memory for all of them, and only then can start fetching. That means that for a 32 bit range (an example  mentioned in the question) you need to set `topLimit=2**32`. This code will run into time and memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well,you can generate random no. inside the range of two no.

```
 public static int getRandomVal(int min, int max) {
    Random random = new Random();

    return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}

public static void getRandomNumbers(int size, int min,
        int max) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (numbers.size() < size) {
        int random = getRandomVal(min, max);

        if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
            numbers.add(random);
            System.out.println(" "+random);
        }
    }
}
```

now to generate 10 different no. between 50 and 100 you can use

```
getRandomNumbers(10, 50,100);
```

This approach is very easy I am creating an array and just checking the random value if it is already present or not. If it is not present I am pushing it to the array and outputting it.

Comment: You're using Java. This is JavaScript. http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: If you understand the logic you can surely change it to javascript....javascript also has math.random() function

Comment: If you're going to shuffle the values in your range, you might as well use a [more efficient shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  You can easily modify this to stop after `n` elements.

Answer (score -1):

Get yourself a seeded random number generator.

Seed with 1, return next random number. Seed with 2, return next random number. Seed with 3, return next random number...
If you seed with an integer then the next random number will be repeatable and pseudo random.

Comment: They aren't guaranteed to be unique in this case...

Comment: They are when you choose your RNG and for a range of integers that can be large.