# Javascript - how to prevent duplicates when randomly selecting from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, duplicates

I have an array of 100 **“XYCoordinate”** objects, and I want to randomly select 25 of them and assign them to 25 **"Cube"** objects so I can present those cubes on the screen in different locations.

Obviously I need to make sure that I don’t accidentally randomly select the same **XYCoordinate** twice and assign it to two different **Cube** objects - cause then they’ll sit right on top of each other.

I thought the following code would work, but I’m *still* getting duplicates:

```
   // I first declare an array to store the randomly selected XYCoordinate objects:
   var selectedCoordObjectsArray = [];

   // I then declare a second array to store just the INDEXES of the Coords that 
   // were already randomly selected:
   var selectedCoordIDNumbersArray = [];
    
        
   // Next I make a function to randomly select one XYCoordinate object:
   function selectRandomXYCoordinateObject() {
       let randomCoordNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

       // Check if this Coord-number was already selected:
       if(selectedCoordIDNumbersArray.includes(randomCoordNumber)) {
           // A Coord of this ID was already selected!
           console.log(“Duplicate!”);
           // Immediately call this function again:
           selectRandomXYCoordinateObject();
       }
       else { 
          // Grab this Coord from my previously declared “coordsArray”:
          let chosenCoord = coordsArray[randomCoordNumber];
          // Add the INDEX of this Coord to the “selectedCoordIDNumbersArray”:
          selectedCoordIDNumbersArray.push(randomCoordNumber);
          // Finally, return the actual “chosenCoord” object: 
          return chosenCoord;
       }
   }
```

Here’s where I call this function:

```
   function makeCubes() {
       for(var cubeCounter = 0; cubeCounter < 25; cubeCounter++) {
          let tempCube = cubesArray[cubeCounter];
          // prep the Cube, give it different Width & Height, Color, etc. 
          // Then, assign to it a random coordinate: 
          tempCube.coords = selectRandomXYCoordinateObject();
            
          // an then display the “tempCube” at those coords:
           . . .
       }
   }
```

So what’s happening is that every time the `selectRandomXYCoordinateObject` function comes upon a duplicate - the App crashes!
The function *does recognize* when it’s got a duplicate on it's hands - and it ***does*** call itself again - but the `makeCubes` function seems to not be able to wait for that second execution. It seems as though it’s already moved along, and it's trying to display the `tempCube` at it's would-be coords.

I tried solving this using `async` and `await` but that didn't work - and I really don't wanna go barking up the `Promises` tree - just feels like I'm missing something here and that there should be a straight-forward solution...?

Comment: Might be cleaner to simply create a copy of the original Array and just splice each item from that copy every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partly a guess, but you don't return the value that the recursive call to `selectRandomXYCoordinateObject()` returned:

```js
       // Check if this Coord-number was already selected:
       if(selectedCoordIDNumbersArray.includes(randomCoordNumber)) {
           // A Coord of this ID was already selected!
           console.log(“Duplicate!”);
           // Immediately call this function again:
           selectRandomXYCoordinateObject();
       }
```

Instead of:

```js
       // Check if this Coord-number was already selected:
       if(selectedCoordIDNumbersArray.includes(randomCoordNumber)) {
           // A Coord of this ID was already selected!
           console.log(“Duplicate!”);
           // Immediately call this function again:
           return selectRandomXYCoordinateObject();
       }
```

So the first call to `selectRandomXYCoordinateObject()` returns `undefined`, and assuming you're trying to access properties of the returned object in the callee, you'll get a `TypeError` and crash.

**Edit:** By the way, this is not the best method to sample an array uniquely - see [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1).

Comment: Interesting - it's not crashing anymore - but it's STILL giving me duplicates. Very weird...

Comment: No. That's what I'm saying: it's not crashing anymore. It's RUNNING ok - BUT, it's still giving me duplicates.

Comment: Maybe there are duplicates in the coords array?

Comment: Yeah I was just starting to look at that... I'll let you know

Comment: OK - what you suspected - and what I suspected - was indeed true: I had duplicates in my coords array (which actually has 10,000 coordinate objects, not 100!)  I generated them algorithmically, 2500 per each quadrant, so yes, I had duplicates. And your suggestion to use `return` works! Thank you!