# Reducing rand() pool in C

Tags: c, random, simulation

I'm currently building a plane loading simulation, and am using the `rand()` function in C to generate a random number between 0 and some upper bound in order to allocate passengers to their seats.

Therefore, once a passenger has been allocated, I don't want the `rand()` function to select that passengers seat/row again. That is, I want that number to be taken out of the selection pool that `rand()` selects from.

Is there a way to do this? I know I can simply check if it has been selected and re-select if it has, but I was wondering if there was another way.

Thanks!

Btw, here is a snippet of the code for some context

```
int row = rand() % amount_rows/2; // don't want to select the same row/col twice
int col = rand() % amount_cols;
        
if (1 != passengers[row][col].in_row) {
    passengers[row][col].in_row = 1;
}
```

Comment: there is no pool behind rand, so you should either check and regenerate numbers or generate array with all possible variants and randomly shuffle it, like card deck shuffling

Comment: Ya that's what I thought. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196017/unique-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-o1