# Randomly initialize BitSet in JAVA

Tags: java, random

I have BitSet which has to be initialized randomly. Is there any method to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just go through BitSet and call nextBoolean() of the Random class.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Java 7, you can initialize a random *byte* array with [`Random.nextBytes(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes(byte[])) then use the static [`BitSet.valueOf(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf(byte[])) method to create a `BitSet` from the same byte array.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
// ...
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[NUM_BYTES];
rnd.nextBytes(randomBytes);
return BitSet.valueOf(randomBytes);
```

Or if you want the proportion of `0` vs. `1` bits to be something other than 50:50, check out [an old SO question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2075912/12048).

Answer (score 4):

There is no such constructor. What you'd have to do is create a BitSet and then in a loop set all bits to random values.

Comment: Setting all bits of an unbounded vector of bits is going to take a while... might be worth calling out explicitly that the OP will have to determine how many bits to set.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming a BitSet of fixed length.