# Randomly initialize BitSet with specific length

Tags: java, bit, bitset

I have two BitSets which have to be initialized randomly with the length of 20 bits.

I am trying to achieve that by initializing the BitSets with 20 bits each and within a for loop iterating through the BitSets and call nextBoolean() of the Random class. However, the length is not always 20. So, I have been playing around with it, and figured it that it might be because it does not count the false bits as part of the length. In case I understand it correctly, how do I force it to have 20 random bits always?

```
public static void generate() {

        BitSet set1 = new BitSet(20);
        BitSet set2 = new BitSet(20);

        Random r = new SecureRandom();
        for (int i = 0; set1.length() < 20 && set2.length() < 20; i++) {
            set1.set(i, r.nextBoolean());
            set2.set(i, r.nextBoolean());
        }

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < set1.length(); i++) {
            s.append(temp1.get(i) == true ? 1 : 0);
        }

        System.out.println(s + " " + s.length() + " " + set1.length() + " "+ set2.length());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you always want 20 as your size, why not use a constant? Something like `final int size = 20;`. Then you can replace all occurrences of `20` with `size`

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I have tried that, but it did not resolve the problem, unfortunately. The length is still inconsistent and now it goes above 20 sometimes

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69148389/139985.  Basically, the `Bitset` class model represents a bitset with an infinite number of bits.  The "logical length" returned by `length()` denotes the position of the rightmost ONE bit.  So your idea of a bitset with precisely 20 bits randomly 0 or 1 does not fit the model.  (Or  to put it another way, its `length()` may not be 20.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In case I understand it correctly, how do I force it to have 20 random bits always?

Change your for-loops to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    set1.set(i, r.nextBoolean());
    set2.set(i, r.nextBoolean());
}

...

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    s.append(temp1.get(i) == true ? 1 : 0);
}
```

A `BitSet` is backed by a `long[]` and all bits are initially set to `false`, so calling `BitSet#length` will not return the value `20` unless the `19`th bit happens to be set, as stated by its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#length()):

> Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one. Returns zero if the BitSet contains no set bits.

By using the value `20` as the condition in your for-loops, you're ensuring that the first `20` bits will have the opportunity of being set randomly.

Comment: So even if I change my for loops and print the BitSet length, I won't always get 20 bits? An example of my print: `10101001110111111110 20 19 20`. 20 is the length of the StringBuilder, 19 is the length of the first BitSet and 20 is the length of the second BitSet

Comment: There's a 50% chance you'll get a length of `20`, as it depends on the last bit set by the for-loop. But if you use `20` as the condition in the for-loop, you can be sure that the first `20` bits will be set randomly, even if `BitSet#length` doesn't return `20`.

Comment: I see. What must I do in order to ensure that there are exactly 20 random bits then? i.e. 20 in length

Comment: By just changing the for-loop condition. `BitSet#length` depends on the last bit set, so don't rely on its value, as you're setting bits randomly.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you; I understand that I have to change the for loops, but what confuses me then is that when I print the length of the BitSet after the for loops, it is inconsistent. I do understand that if I print `s` I will get 20, but that is not the real BitSet's length. Would an if statement, which always sets the 20th bit to true help?

Comment: You would have to set the bit at index `19` to `true` for `BitSet#length` to return `20` (assuming no bit after that has been set). But I would think that defeats the purpose of what you're trying to do. Even if `BitSet#length` does not return `20`, you're still setting the first `20` bits to `true` or `false` randomly. For that reason, DO NOT depend on what `BitSet#length` returns.

Comment: Ahh, I was trying to set the bit at index 20 to true. Oversaw that it is LESS than 20 - Back to basics.  However, it does not defeat the purpose of what I am trying to do as I need the length to be exactly 20

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Bitset.valueOf(byte[] array)` to initialize the bit set from a random byte array?

Something like:

```
public BitSet getBits(SecureRandom sr, int size) {
    byte[] ar = new byte[(int) Math.ceil(size / 8F)];
    sr.nextBytes(ar);
    return BitSet.valueOf(ar).get(0, size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7, you can initialize a random byte array with Random.nextBytes(byte[]) then use the static BitSet.valueOf(byte[]) method to create a BitSet from the same byte array.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
// ...
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[NUM_BYTES];
rnd.nextBytes(randomBytes);
return BitSet.valueOf(randomBytes);
```

Credits for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8566871/5133329