# How to populate a BitSet with 0s?

Tags: java, bitset

I am trying to populate a size 32 BitSet with all 0s.
When I do longWord.set(i); it populates with all i values.
When I do longWord.set(i,false); it doesn't populate at all.
how can I set all 32 bits to 0?

```
longWord = new BitSet(32);

        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
        {
            longWord.set(i);
        }
        System.out.println(longWord);
```

Comment: They are 0 initially.

Comment: ... and it only creates internal array elements as necessary to hold 1 bits. If you haven't set any 1s the internal array could be empty. There is no problem here to solve.

Comment: @tkausl My output is an empty set i.e {}. So the bits are there but are not printed?

Comment: @user207421 Ah I believe that's the information I was looking for. I was confused why it was printing an empty set when all initial bits should be set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do does not make sense ... given the model that `Bitset` provides.

Conceptually, a `Bitset` represents an **infinite** set of bits.  While a `Bitset` has a `length()` method, what it returns is this:

> the index of the highest set bit in the `BitSet` plus one. Returns zero if the `BitSet` contains no set bits.

This is described as the "logical size".

But you want to represent a conceptual "array of bits" where unset (i.e. zero) bits are part of the bitset's "size".

There are a couple of approaches to solving this:

- Represent your conceptual length separately from the `Bitset` object; e.g. using an `int` variable.
- Write a simple wrapper class for `Bitset` that behaves the way you want; i.e. one that implements an explicit `length` field.
- Look for an alternative bitset class that behaves the way that you want.

Comment: I see. So when I print out the longword after declaring`longWord = new BitSet(32);`, It is printing {}, an empty set. Are you not able to see false values by printing BitSet? From the Bitset documentation, it looked as if this would initially be set to false yet I can't see that.

Comment: Correct.  The `32` is just a hint to the constructor to allocate space for 32 bits.  If you read the documentation carefully it says that all bits are false ... not that they are explicitly set to false ... or how many bits there are.

Comment: So I am allocating space for the bits and not populating them? In the BitSet documentation it says "Creates a new bit set. All bits are initially false." If I'm just allocating storage what is the point of that function?

Comment: The point is the same as `new ArrayList(32)`.  To preallocate space.  But you are still not understanding what the length of a `Bitset` actually means.  As I said, a Bitset denotes an infinite set of bits.  So, even if the constructor did explicitly initialize some of them to zero, the length as returned by `length()` is the position of the right-most NON-zero bit; i.e. 0.

Comment: I see, so given my current approach what would cause the BitSet to print empty? Are all bits set to false and an empty allocation treated in the same manner?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.  So, i you want to treat "rightmost" zero bits as significant when you print the bitset, you need to use one of the approaches I suggested in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

A BitSet's values are initialized as false by default so doing just:
`longWord = new BitSet(32);` should give what you want.

I am not sure what you mean by

> When I do longWord.set(i,false); it doesn't populate at all.

Looking at the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) I can see you should be getting a longWord with all values set to false. If that's not the case, could you post what `System.out.println(longWord);` printed?

**Edit**:

Looking at it, it seems like the toString() method would result in {} if all values are set to 0. The values are set to false, they are just not printed.
Doing

```
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    System.out.println(longWord.get(i));
}
```

would make that obvious. When you print them after setting them all to true you get the indexes of the bits that are set to true (in your case all of them). To see that simply do:

```
BitSet longWord = new BitSet(32);
longWord.set(26);
System.out.println(longWord);
```

and you will see only 26 in the print.

Comment: It just printed {}. Does that mean it is populated but I can't see the values?
longWord.set(i); printed {1,2,3,...,32}