# cpp show result depends on the previous result

Tags: c++, random

We have button. User clicking the button and receive `action1` or `action2` depended by variable `percent_to_action2`(from 0 to 100). The simplest way to give him `action1` or `action2` is based on `rand() % 100` and comparison with `percent_to_action2`.

But the problem is that if eg. `perfect_to_action = 50` there is no guaranty that after first random `action1` user will get `action2` (by rand()). I am searching the ways to avoid many repeating actions. Please, **suggest how to count more accurately considering the previous event/or all events.** with examples and comments.   Goal is to avoid excessive number of repeating actions that rund() can give. for example with percent = 50 rand() can give 10/10 action2!

ps. `perfect_to_action` can be changed at any time.
pps. sorry for me english.

**my code:**

```
                int num_rand = (rand() % 100 ) + 1; // from 1 to 100
                if (  num_rand <= current_percent_to_action2 )
                {
                    // action 1
                } else {} // action2
```

What I want in examples:

percent = 50:
action1 than action2 than action1 than action2 etc.

percent = 33: 
(first by rand)
if first action1 than action1 than action2 than action1 than action1 than action2 etc.

Comment: You've given us your current model, but you haven't told us what you're modeling. What are these actions? [What is your goal](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)?

Comment: Is this homework? Consider tagging as such. This might lead to people having a little bit more patience. I find this question unintelligible right now

Comment: So you want to guarantee that after they randomly get one, that the next button press will give the other?

Comment: @GManNickG Goal is to avoid excessive number of repeating actions that rund() can give. for example with `percent = 50` rand() can give 10/10 action2!

Comment: @abrahab: What would you like instead?  5/10 every single time?  That's harder to do.

Comment: @MooingDuck the simplified logic if `percent = 50` but if its less, I think only need to reduce the likelihood of action that already showed.

Comment: @sehe no, its not. I know only php and cpp. and wrote this on cpp. threfore, its easy to understand examples on familiar lang.

Comment: What is the actual requirement for the distribution of results? Its clearly not random, since random numbers have no memory and you can get action1 every time and thats still good because the next time it might be action2. Decide what you want first. Then coding it is easier.

Comment: @Julian Seems for users its no good to get the same action each time if `percent` suggests others.

Comment: So what is good? Your specification is currently contradictory and you can't deliver against it. You need a specification that defines the acceptable outcomes. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2060774/1002025 for a similar discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static unsigned num_action_1 = 1;
static unsigned num_action_2 = 1;
double bias = double(num_action_2)/num_action_1;
double randomchance = 1.0-current_percent_to_action2/100.0;
double action_1_cutoff = RAND_MAX*randomchance*bias;
if (  rand() <= action_1_cutoff ) {
    // action 1
    ++num_action_1;
} else {
    // action2
    ++num_action_2;
}
```

This will bias the randomness toward the option that has happened less frequently.  I also changed it so that action 2 will happen roughly `current_percent_to_action2` percent of the time, instead of action 1 like in your code.  As you can see by this chart, it adds a lot of complexity, but you are far less likely to get unbalanced numbers of results.  In the long term, these will end up virtually identical though, both will give strings of 10 in a row eventually, this code just starts far more even.

```
times #1     Even distribution    Biased distribution
    1               50%                  50%
    2               25%                   8.3%
    3               12.5%                 3.125%
    4                6.25%                1.25%
    5                3.13%                0.52%
    6                1.56%                0.22%
    7                0.78%                0.09%
    8                0.39%                0.04%
    9                0.20%                0.02%
    10               0.10%                0.01%
```

Comment: `action_1_cutoff` counted, but does not used. seems need to compare with rand() ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want actions repeated, you can either a) choose from all BUT the last action, or b) choose as you do now, but keep re-choosing until you get something other than the previous action.  The latter is easier to do, but is slower (possibly a LOT slower).