# How do I pick for example 2,7,9 or 14 users form the db that get UPDATED?

Tags: php, mysql

First I want to pick all the specific users. I think this is done like this?

```
$res= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE test='$value'");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);

echo $num;
```

Lets say there are 37 users who achieves the requirements in the `SELECT($num=37)`. How do I pick 7 random users of those 37 who I then UPDATE?

Comment: possible help http://stackoverflow.com/q/32035566/689579

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE test='$value'
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use append

```
Order by rand() limit 7
```

To the query Or get all results and use array shuffle

The first way is easier to implement the second will perform faster for larger datasets