# Random selection

Tags: algorithm, random

Given two integer numbers N and n (N >= n > 0), how do I generate random selection (without repetition!) of [0, N) with length = n?
E.g. Given N = 5, n = 3 possible solutions are (3,0,2) or (2,4,1), etc.

There is a restriction that prevents of using naive approach: memory usage must be O(n), not O(N).

/*
Under naive approach I mean usage of temporary array of size=N that's initially filled in with numbers 0..N-1 in order. Required n items are selected randomly from this array.
*/

Comment: You should probably make the title more informative. "Random selection" doesn't say much.

Comment: Did you try searching for past questions on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to select a single, random combination of values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394246/algorithm-to-select-a-single-random-combination-of-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go through all the numbers m from 0 to N, deciding whether to include m in the set as encountered. You need to update the probability of including the next number based on the numbers already treated.

Let's apply this idea to the example given, with n=3 and N=5. First consider m=0. There are 3 numbers remaining, and 5 possibilities, so 0 is in the set with probability 3/5. Use a random number generator to decide to include the number or not. Now consider m=1. If you included 0 in the set, then you have 2 numbers remaining and 4 possibilities, so it should be included with probability 2/4, but if 0 is not included, you have 3 numbers remaining and 4 possibilities and thus 1 should be included with probability 3/4. This continues until the required 3 numbers are included in the set.

Here's an implementation in Python:

```
from __future__ import division
import random

def rand_set(n, N):
    nums_included=set()
    for m in range(N):
        prob = (n-len(nums_included)) / (N-m)
        if random.random() < prob:
            nums_included.add(m)
    return nums_included
```

You could (and probably should) add in a test to see when you've got enough numbers in your set, and break out of the loop early.

The numbers are stored in a set, which varies in size from 0 to n, so the storage used is `O(n)`. Everything else uses constant space, so it's overall `O(n)`.

EDIT Actually, you can go a little further with this approach, so that it takes constant space. In Python, just make a generator based on the above:

```
def rand_set_iter(n, N):
    num_remaining = n
    m = 0
    while num_remaining > 0:
        prob = num_remaining / (N-m)
        if random.random() < prob:
            num_remaining -= 1
            yield m
        m += 1
```

Here, I've gone ahead and used a while loop instead of the for loop. To store the results, you'll of course need to use `O(n)` space. But if all you need to do is iterate through the numbers, the generator version does it in `O(1)`.

For a language without generators, you can roll your own generator, calling a function repeatedly and updating a static or global variable.

Comment: Excellent. Definitely the way to go.

Comment: This is called Reservoir Sampling, I believe.

Comment: @Moron I never knew the name for the approach. Thanks!

Comment: A Mary Poppins answer. Practically perfect in every way.

Answer (score 2):

The *simple* (but potentially very inefficient) solution is just to build a list by repeatedly picking a value in the desired range, and checking whether or not you've already picked it. This has an unbounded maximum time, because you *could* always end up accidentally picking something you've already picked.

I have a vague inkling of an O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution which in each iteration picks a value in the range `[0, N - i)` where `i` is the number of elements you've already got... and then 
mapping that new value onto the range `[0, N)` by going through the existing picked elements and adding 1 if you find you've already got a value less than or equal to the value you've picked. You'd need to think about it carefully, but that's effectively the approach I'd look into.

Comment: Even your simple solution is pretty good.  If n < N/2, then expected number of failures is never more than 2.  +1!

Answer (score 1):

In python, this would be really easy:

```
selection = random.shuffle(range(N))[:n]
```

This is O(N) in memory, since the list of valid values is generated first and then shuffled in place, so it fails on your requirement :(

You could try something like this:

```
N = 5
n = 3
selection = set()
while len(selection) < n:
    selection += pick_random_int(0, N)
```

Which is essentially what Jon Skeet proposed. This will work well for n << N, but start to fail horribly with n close to N. In that case, though, the O(n) and O(N) memory solutions will converge anyway and your requirement is moot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Divide the interval [0,N] to n intervals. From each interval select a random number and then randomize the result. The problem is that in this situation the the distribution is not uniformed.