# selection of numbers from a set with equal probability

Tags: algorithm, random, numbers, set

Got this question from algorithms design manual by Steven Skiena.

It is required to select k (value given) numbers to form a subset S' from a given set S having n numbers, such that selection probability for each number is equal (k/n).
n is unknown (i was thinking of taking S as a link-list for this).
also, we can have only pass through the set S.

Comment: Essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416567/random-selection/5417178#5417178

Comment: I think the problem is different because n is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
for elem in S
  if random() < (k - S'.size)/S.size // This is float division
    S'.add(elem)
```

The first element is chosen with probability `k/n`, the second one with `(n-k)/n * k/(n-1) + k/n * (k-1)/(n-1)` which reduces to `k/n`, etc.

Comment: According to the formula you've provided you should take into account the index i of elem (starting with 1), hence having   random() < (k - S'.size)/(S.size - i) // Float division

Comment: This answer doesn't work if S.size is unknown, which is a condition given in the original question

Comment: That's right. I can't delete, since it's accepted, but it seems the other answer is correct.

Answer (score 6):

When **n is unknown** you'd rather need an *on-line algorithm* for so-called **Reservoir sampling**.

The good explanation & proof sketches are provided here http://propersubset.com/2010/04/choosing-random-elements.html

I mean this algorithm implemented in Python (taken from the link above)

```
import random
def random_subset( iterator, K ):
    result = []
    N = 0

    for item in iterator:
        N += 1
        if len( result ) < K:
            result.append( item )
        else:
            s = int(random.random() * N)
            if s < K:
                result[ s ] = item

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You should choose an algorithm that can truly simulate the real activity "Randomly choose k numbers from n numbers".Your algorithm should has two properties

(1) It must return k numbers at end.

(2) It must truly simulate that properties of target activity : each number is selected with probability k/n.

Oborok`s answer is wrong because it hasn`t first property.

```
for i = 0 to n
randomly choose an integer number between [1,n-i+1]
if [randomValue <= (k - S'.size)/(S.size - i + 1)] then
    S'.add(S[i])
```

With above selecting plan,each number is selected with probability k/n.You can see that by prove below equation  :

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=677984275648191&l=7cafe5d468