# Random Selection from Array into new Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have seen this question [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416567/random-selection) here, but I have an additional question that is related.

## Im trying to achieve:

the same thing, but, with the *output being a selection of more than 1 number*, the above works fine if you only want a single value returned.

How can I return (x) amount of outputs #7 in this case into a new var or array ...? Some guidance on best practice will also be appreciated ;)

### **Thanks a bunch....**

---

Just for fun,
Objective:

Create a  teeny weenie web App that returns 7 variable numbers in a range [ 1 - 49 ] into an array.
`
Think return a list of Lotto Numbers
Create new array from selection using _underscore.js [Sample function]

****  I know this is easier, but im trying to get an understanding 
of using Vanilla JS to accomplish this

_.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3); => [1, 6, 2]

---

```
var getLoot = Array.from(Array(50).keys()) // Create array of 49 numbers.
console.info(getLoot);
var pick = getLoot[Math.floor(Math.random() * getLoot.length)];

pick;
```

// pick returns a single which is fine if you want a single but, ..
// I want something like this :

```
var pick = function() {
    // code that will return 7 numbers from the array into a new Array
    // will randomize every time pick is called...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return more than just 1 value you can store your results into a data structure like [an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Here is a solution to the problem
assuming you can pass in your array of 50 numbers into the `pick()` funciton.:

```
var getRandomArbitrary = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var pick = function(fiftyNumberArray, numberOfValuesWanted) {
    var randomNums = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfValuesWanted; i++) {
        randomNums.push(
            fiftyNumberArray[getRandomArbitrary(0, 50)]
        );
    }
    return randomNums;
};

var fiftyNumbers = [] // <- set your array of fifty numbers
pick(fiftyNumbers, 7);
```

Javascript's `Math.random()` will return a value in between 0 and 1 (exclusive). So to get an index scaled up to the correct value to look into your array, you would want to multiply that by the formula `(max - min) + min`

Comment: It sounds like what’s wanted is a function that won’t return the same element twice.

Comment: Oh I read `// will randomize every time pick is called...` as in, it will return a random subset of your original array, but not ensured that it is different. `pick` will always return a random set of numbers from the original 50 which I believe solves the OP's comment.

Comment: Thanks @httpNick, that is indeed what I was looking for, and also thanks to Ryan,....it would seem that, it can also be an option ~didnt think about that. will try some permutation now ;) ....Either way thanks a lot guy's got what i was after *thumbs up*

Comment: @httpNick `pick` returns array where each value is `undefined`, here. Should `getRandomArbitrary` return `Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)`?

Comment: you're correct, thank you @guest271314. updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want.

```
$(function() 
{
    var lol = [1,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    function getPart(array,number)
    {
        var part = [],
            index;
        while(true)
        {
            if(part.length == number)
            {
                break;
            }
            index = $.random(0,part.length);
            part.push(lol.splice(index,1));

        }
        return part;
    }
});
$.random = function(min,max,filter)
{

    var i,
        n = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    if(filter != undefined && filter.constructor == Array)
    {
        for(i=filter.length-1;i>-1;i--)
        {
            if(n == filter[i])
            {
                n = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)
                i = filter.length;
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: That’s a lot of jQuery (?) for something that has nothing to do with jQuery and a very strange algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.splice()`, `Math.floor()`, `Math.random()`, `for` loop to remove elements from input array, return an array containing pseudo randomly picked index from input array without duplicate indexes being selected.

```js
function rand(n) {
  var res = []; var a = Array.from(Array(n).keys()); 
  for (;a.length;res.push(a.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length),1)[0]));
  return res
}

console.log(rand(50));
```

Comment: Thanks guest271314, i still need to understand using prototypes better to be able to use it this way, but thanks will def keep it in my arsenal ,

Answer (score 0):

One good way of doing this job is shuffling the array and picking the first `n` values. Such as;

```js
function shuffle(a){
  var i = a.length,
      j,
    tmp;
  while (i > 1) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--);
    tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
  }
  return a;
};
var arr = Array(50).fill().map((_,i) => i+1); //[1,2,3...49,50]
randoms = shuffle(arr).slice(0,7)             // to get 7 random numbers from arrary arr
console.log(randoms)
```

Comment: Oooee' Redu.  I like that idee, brings a lot of possibilities to mind' thanks!!!!

Comment: @Hendrik Exact copy of the real life job done by the playing cards. :)