# You have one billion numbers, implement getRandom() which returns a random number from them

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to select a single, random combination of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394246/algorithm-to-select-a-single-random-combination-of-values)

This is an interview question i've seen online.

> You have one billion numbers, implement getRandom() which returns a
>   random number from them.
>
> Constaints:
>   1. No duplicate returning value.
>   2. getRandom() will at most be invoked 100 million times.
>   Then optimize for space.

How is this solution, and what are some better ones?:

Shuffle the array of numbers. Keep a counter starting at 0. Everytime the user calls getRandom, return the value at counter index. Increment the counter.

Comment: Randomizing an array in order to retrieve 1/10 of its elements is very inefficient.

Comment: Randomize just the first 100 mill elements then?

Comment: That will generate numbers from only 1/10 of the set, which isn't really random.

Comment: Are the numbers in the original set unique?

Comment: do you have already some randomization primitive or do you have to do it from scratch

Comment: Please clarify if the numbers are sequential (within the set, but out of order), or if any of the numbers can have duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Lets assume that you have a random function that returns `1` or `0` with equal probability.
You can call this function `32` times to get a random number between `0` to `2^(32)-1`.
You can call this function `64` times to get a random number between `0` to `2^(64)-1`.