# Random numbers reoccur when generating with arc4random

Tags: ios, swift, random

I need to make random choices from the questions in my quiz app, but this code I've written repeats numbers. How can I prevent the repeats?

```
var correctans = num1.text!.toInt()! + num2.text!.toInt()!
    var randomans1 = (arc4random()%8) + 1
    var randomans2 = (arc4random()%7) + 1
    var randomans3 = (arc4random()%6) + 1
    var randomans4 = (arc4random()%5) + 1


    switch (randomplace) {

        case 1:

            btn3.setTitle("\(correctans)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btn4.setTitle("\(randomans1)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btn2.setTitle("\(randomans3)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            btn1.setTitle("\(randomans4)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            break
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I'd recommend putting all the choices in an array then randomly pulling them out of the array one by one to set the title.

Comment: How would i go about that I'm not great with arrays?

Comment: means you are saying out of 4 random answer you are getting same number multiple times?

Comment: Further reading (which leads to further reading): [Non-repeating arc4random_uniform](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10233517)