# Compare all elements within a single array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Just want to start off apologizing if this has been answered and just should be worded differently so I was unable to find it. I've been working on this particular problem for a few hours and it's possible my Google Fu is weak atm.

For my c++ class I have to create a random number generator that collects data from the user to specify the number of digits the numbers must be and the number of rands to create. I can create the randoms just fine, the only problem is the numbers can not duplicate at any point and the if loop I created at the end to decrement returns true always and I can't figure out why. Because of this, the loop never moves on to increment i. If I'm not mistaken, it should not even be possible to have a duplicate entry on the first try right?

```
void TargetGen::genNumbers()
{
    int mod = 0;
    int baseMod = 0;

    if(Digits != 1)
    {
        baseMod = pow(10.0,(Digits -1));
    }
    mod = (pow(10.0,Digits))-baseMod;


    for(int i=0;i<Numbers;i++)
    {
        cout << "front of i loop, value of i: " << i << endl;
        int randomTemp;

        randomTemp = rand() % mod + baseMod;

        targets[i] = randomTemp;
        cout << "rand: " << targets[i] << endl;
        for(int k = 0;k <= Numbers; k++)
        {
            if(targets[k] == targets[i])
            {
                cout << targets[i] << endl;
                i--;
            }
            cout << " k looping, k value: " << k << endl;
            cout << " k loop, value of i: " << i << endl;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easiest way to avoid duplicates, and do not keep all numbers in the memory -- to use sequenced numbers 1,2,..N, and encrypt each by any symmetric block cypher, for example, DES. Since number can be decrypted back, then impossible have 2 differrent inputs, whose maps to same cryptogram.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to select a single, random combination of values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394246/algorithm-to-select-a-single-random-combination-of-values)

Comment: Make `target` a `std::set` and keep adding random numbers until you get to the desired size.

Comment: The loop over `k` should likely be `for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) ...`. Otherwise, the loop will always reach `k == i`, at which point, of course, `targets[k] == targets[i]` and you are not making any progress.

Comment: The problem statement sounds strange to me though. A random number generator that doesn't repeat itself is not really very random: if you throw a die six times, do you expect it to produce six distinct numbers very often? Also, if I ask you to generate 1000 2-digit numbers, you are going to have a difficult time.

Comment: I actually have added logic in another function to disallow requesting more numbers than would be possible to present. But I do agree, RNG without duplication seems silly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized "targets" anywhere? I'm a little weak in c++ (i haven't coded in it in years), but I don't see it it declared anywhere...so I'm guessing that it's always returning true because targets isn't initialized anywhere...I could be wrong though.

Comment: If it hadn't been declared, the code would not compile. It looks like it's an attribute of the class.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense.  That's what I get for coding in python for too long >__<

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is comparing the new entry against all entries in the array, including itself.  Limit k to be less than i and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the advice from Zac Howland from the comments, use a `set` instead of a vector and keep checking the size, or rather whether the insertion took place. Something like:

```
int insertedNumbers = 0;
set<int> targets;
while (insertedNumbers != Numbers) {
    int randomTemp = rand() % mod + baseMod;

    pair<set<int>::iterator, bool> insertionResult = targets.insert(randomTemp);

    if(insertionResult.second) insertedNumbers ++;
}

cout << "Random numbers:" << targets.size() << endl; // Should equal Numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions for you:

1) rand() normally requires seeding.  If every time you run it you get the same number, you're probably forgetting to seed:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

2) If you can't repeat the random numbers you're generating, and you're not creating an incredibly large number of them, you might want to put each result into a set or a sorted list.  That way you can just check against what you know you have created.

3)  generally Numbers would indicate a class since the N is capitalized.  Use numberOfNumbers if you must, it's a clearer variable name.