# How to generate random pairs of numbers in Python, including pairs with one entry being the same and excluding pairs with both entries being the same?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm using Python and was using numpy for this.
I want to generate pairs of random numbers. I want to exclude *repetitive* outcomes of pairs with both entries being the same number and I want to include pairs which only have one entry being the same number.I tried to use

```
import numpy
numpy.random.choice(a,(m,n),replace=False)
```

for it, but it excludes any tupels with the the same entries completely, i.e.

```
import numpy
numpy.random.choice(a=2,(m=2,n=1),replace=False)
```

gives me only (1,0) and (0,1) and not (1,1), (0,0), (1,0) and (0,1).

I want to do this because I want to draw a sample of random tuples with a large a and large n(as used above) without getting exactly the same tupels more then once. It also should be more or less efficient. Is there a way that's already implemented to do this?

Comment: I've read this three times, and I still don't get it. If you want to exclude pairs where both entries are the same number, then you *should* exclude (1,1) and (0,0) - could you explain why you're unhappy with the result you have?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, was falsely written, corrected it. If stil unclear please comment

Comment: You can think of it as random position in an X-Y plane and I never want to hit the same position twice, but I do want to hit the same position in X with different Y, which isn't possibe with my solution

Comment: Then don't you just want a generator to generate a random pair of unique ``(x, y)`` coordinates?

Comment: Thats an easier way to put it, yes..I'm new to coding! I used numpy because I can use numpy.random.seed and reproduce that later.

Answer (score 14):

Generator random unique coordinates:

```
from random import randint

def gencoordinates(m, n):
    seen = set()

    x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)

    while True:
        seen.add((x, y))
        yield (x, y)
        x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)
        while (x, y) in seen:
            x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)
```

Output:

```
>>> g = gencoordinates(1, 100)
>>> next(g)
(42, 98)
>>> next(g)
(9, 5)
>>> next(g)
(89, 29)
>>> next(g)
(67, 56)
>>> next(g)
(63, 65)
>>> next(g)
(92, 66)
>>> next(g)
(11, 46)
>>> next(g)
(68, 21)
>>> next(g)
(85, 6)
>>> next(g)
(95, 97)
>>> next(g)
(20, 6)
>>> next(g)
(20, 86)
```

As you can see coincidentally an `x` coordinate was repeated!

Comment: I'll check back on this later, got a group meeting now. Thank you a lot already for the quick answer

Comment: I implemented lines/the idea of your code and for excercise did my own. Thank you again.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say that your *x* and *y* coordinates are all integers between 0 and *n*. For small *n* a simple method might be to generate the set of all possible *xy* coordinates using `np.mgrid`, reshape it to a `(nx * ny, 2)` array, then sample random rows from this:

```
nx, ny = 100, 200
xy = np.mgrid[:nx,:ny].reshape(2, -1).T
sample = xy.take(np.random.choice(xy.shape[0], 100, replace=False), axis=0)
```

Creating the array of all possible coordinates can become expensive if *nx* and/or *ny* is very large, in which case it might be better to use a generator object and keep track of previously used coordinates, as in James' answer.

---

Following **@morningsun**'s suggestion, an alternative method is to sample from the set of *nx*ny* indices into the flattened array then convert these directly to *x, y* coordinates, which avoids constructing the whole *nx*ny* array of possible *x, y* permutations.

For comparison, here's a version of my original approach generalized for N-dimensional arrays, plus a version that uses the new approach:

```
def sample_comb1(dims, nsamp):
    perm = np.indices(dims).reshape(len(dims), -1).T
    idx = np.random.choice(perm.shape[0], nsamp, replace=False)
    return perm.take(idx, axis=0)

def sample_comb2(dims, nsamp):
    idx = np.random.choice(np.prod(dims), nsamp, replace=False)
    return np.vstack(np.unravel_index(idx, dims)).T
```

There's not a huge difference in practice, but the benefits of the second method become a bit more apparent for larger arrays:

```
In [1]: %timeit sample_comb1((100, 200), 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.59 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit sample_comb2((100, 200), 100)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit sample_comb1((1000, 2000), 100)
1 loops, best of 3: 341 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit sample_comb2((1000, 2000), 100)
1 loops, best of 3: 319 ms per loop
```

---

If you have scikit-learn installed, [`sklearn.utils.random.sample_without_replacement`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/utilities.html#efficient-random-sampling) offers a much faster method for generating random indices without replacement using [Floyd's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394292/1461210):

```
from sklearn.utils.random import sample_without_replacement

def sample_comb3(dims, nsamp):
    idx = sample_without_replacement(np.prod(dims), nsamp)
    return np.vstack(np.unravel_index(idx, dims)).T

In [5]: %timeit sample_comb3((1000, 2000), 100)
The slowest run took 4.49 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an
intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: I thought a random choice of the linear indices would be better, but in practice it's not faster. A limitation of the current numpy.

Answer (score 1):

@James Miles answer is great, but just to avoid endless loops when accidentally asking for too many arguments I suggest the following (it also removes some repetitions):

```
def gencoordinates(m, n):
    seen = set()
    x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)
    while len(seen) < (n + 1 - m)**2:
        while (x, y) in seen:
            x, y = randint(m, n), randint(m, n)
        seen.add((x, y))
        yield (x, y)
    return
```

Note that wrong range of values will still propagate down.