# Why is random.sample faster than numpy's random.choice?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I need a way to sample without replacement a certain array `a`. I tried two approaches (see MCVE below), using `random.sample()` and `np.random.choice`.

I assumed the `numpy` function would be faster, but it turns out it is not. In my tests `random.sample` is ~15% faster than `np.random.choice`.

Is this correct, or am I doing something wrong in my example below? If this is correct, why?

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def timeblock(label):
    start = time.clock()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        end = time.clock()
        print ('{} elapsed: {}'.format(label, end - start))


def f1(a, n_sample):
    return random.sample(range(len(a)), n_sample)


def f2(a, n_sample):
    return np.random.choice(len(a), n_sample, replace=False)


# Generate random array
a = np.random.uniform(1., 100., 10000)
# Number of samples' indexes to randomly take from a
n_sample = 100
# Number of times to repeat functions f1 and f2
N = 100000

with timeblock("random.sample"):
    for _ in range(N):
        f1(a, n_sample)

with timeblock("np.random.choice"):
    for _ in range(N):
        f2(a, n_sample)
```

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2764

Comment: I see, it's a long standing issue. Could you make an answer out of your comment please @ayhan, so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: I think the problem is that `np.random.choice` does random sampling without replacement by generating a permutation of *all* of the indices in your array, then taking the first `n_sample` of these (see [this line](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8c49b92d9b472f1b476b360951b1ac9066f69b4b/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1174)). This becomes quite inefficient if `n_sample` is much smaller than the number of elements in your array `a`.

Comment: On the other hand, `random.sample` only ever draws `n_samples` random samples. It does this in one of two ways - either by keeping track of the items it has selected already (if `n_samples << N`) or by maintaining a shrinking pool of candidate items that can be selected (if `n_samples` is relatively large compared to `N`). You can see the source code [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/random.py#l337) - it's quite simple and readable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR** Since numpy v1.17.0 it's recommended to use `numpy.random.default_rng()` object instead of `numpy.random`. For choice:

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()    # you can pass seed
rng.choice(...)    # interface is the same
```

Besides other changes with random API introduced in v1.17 this new version of choice is much smarter now and should be the fastest in most cases. *The old version remains the same for backward compatibility!*

---

As mentioned in the comments, there was a long-standing issue in numpy regarding `np.random.choice` implementation being ineffective for `k << n` compared to `random.sample` from python standard library.

The problem was `np.random.choice(arr, size=k, replace=False)` being implemented as a `permutation(arr)[:k]`. In case of a large array and a small k, computing the whole array permutation is a waste of time and memory. The standard python's `random.sample` works in a more straightforward way - it just iteratively samples without replacement either keeping track of what is already sampled or from what to sample.

In v1.17.0 numpy introduced rework and improvement of `numpy.random` package ([docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html), [what's new](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/new-or-different.html#new-or-different), [performance](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/performance.html)). I highly recommend to take a look at the first link at least. Note that, as it's said there, for backward compatibility the old `numpy.random` API remains the same - it keeps using an old implementations.

So the new recommended way to use random API is to use `numpy.random.default_rng()` **object** instead of `numpy.random`. Note that it's an object and it accepts optional seed argument as well so you can pass it around in a convenient way. It also uses a different generator by default that is faster in average (see performance link above for the details).

Regarding your case you may want to use `np.random.default_rng().choice(...)` now. Besides being faster, thanks to the improved random generator, the `choice` itself became smarter. Now it uses the whole array permutation only for both sufficiently large array (>10000 elements) and relatively large k (>1/50 of the size). Otherwise it uses Floyd's sampling algorithm ([short description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2394292/1094048), [numpy implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/_generator.pyx#L809)).

---

Here's the performance comparison on my laptop:

100 samples from array of 10000 elements x 10000 times:

```
random.sample elapsed: 0.8711776689742692
np.random.choice elapsed: 1.9704092079773545
np.random.default_rng().choice elapsed: 0.818919860990718
```

1000 samples from array of 10000 elements x 10000 times:

```
random.sample elapsed: 8.785315042012371
np.random.choice elapsed: 1.9777243090211414
np.random.default_rng().choice elapsed: 1.05490942299366
```

10000 samples from array of 10000 elements x 10000 times:

```
random.sample elapsed: 80.15063399000792
np.random.choice elapsed: 2.0218082449864596
np.random.default_rng().choice elapsed: 2.8596064270241186
```

And the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def timeblock(label):
    start = timer()
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        end = timer()
        print ('{} elapsed: {}'.format(label, end - start))


def f1(a, n_sample):
    return random.sample(range(len(a)), n_sample)


def f2(a, n_sample):
    return np.random.choice(len(a), n_sample, replace=False)


def f3(a, n_sample):
    return np.random.default_rng().choice(len(a), n_sample, replace=False)


# Generate random array
a = np.random.uniform(1., 100., 10000)
# Number of samples' indexes to randomly take from a
n_sample = 100
# Number of times to repeat tested functions
N = 100000

print(f'{N} times {n_sample} samples')
with timeblock("random.sample"):
    for _ in range(N):
        f1(a, n_sample)

with timeblock("np.random.choice"):
    for _ in range(N):
        f2(a, n_sample)

with timeblock("np.random.default_rng().choice"):
    for _ in range(N):
        f3(a, n_sample)
```

Comment: Interestingly, `np.random.RandomState().choice` is more than 4 times slower than `np.random.default_rng().choice`

Comment: I realize RandomState is now deprecated.