# Random sample in numba

Tags: python, performance, numba

For performance reasons I often use numba and for my code I need to take a random sample without replacement. I found, that I could use the numpy.random function for that, but I noticed that it is extremely slow compared to the random.sample function. Am I doing something wrong? How could I improve the performance for the numba function? I boiled down my code to this minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def func2():
    List = range(100000)
    for x in range(20000):
        random.sample(List, 10)

@nb.njit()
def func3():
    Array = np.arange(100000)
    for x in range(20000):
        np.random.choice(Array, 10, False)

print(timeit(lambda: func2(), number=1))
print(timeit(lambda: func3(), number=1))
>>>0.1196
>>>20.1245
```

**Edit**: I'm now using my own sample function, which is much faster than np.random.choice.

```
@nb.njit()
def func4():
    for x in range(20000):
        rangeList = list(range(100000))
        result = []
        for x in range(10):
            randint = random.randint(0, len(rangeList) - 1)
            result.append(rangeList.pop(randint))
        return result
print(timeit(lambda: func4(), number=count))
>>>0.1767
```

Comment: The perfomance is decreased by `replace=False`, try to set it True

Comment: Yeah, but I want to have it without replacement!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914862/why-is-random-sample-faster-than-numpys-random-choice

Comment: Thats not really an answer to my question.

Comment: Well it explains why random sample is sometimes faster than numpys random choice. And also how to overcome this a bit by using `np.random.default_rng().choice`. You are asking if you're doing something wrong, and the answer to this is: depends

Comment: Numba is used to optimize the performance of  non-vectorized code, `np.random.choice` is a vectorized function that will not really be speeded up, but actually be slower using jit. You can easily check this by comparing the jitted version to a non-jitted (which is about three times slower) if you include compilation time, excluding compilation time it's twice as fast..

Comment: I did all that. I'm surprised that my speed difference is so much larger and what I wonder what I could do about it. random.default_rng() is still much slower and has no numba support.Since this is part of a larger numba function I'm trying to optimize it for numba.

Comment: I would be surprised if `func3()` does not compile to no-op nowadays, as it always return None.

Comment: Also the outermost loop in `func4()` is useless.

Comment: @HighwayJohn I'd recommend checking out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

In general `np.random.choice(replace=False)` performs well and generally better than `random.sample()` (which cannot be used inside Numba JITted functions in NoPython mode anyway), but for smaller value of `k` it is best to use `random_sample_shuffle_idx()`, except when `k` is very small, in which case `random_sample_set()` should be used.

Parallel Numba compilation may speed up execution for sufficiently large inputs, but will result in race conditions potentially invalidating the sampling, and it is therefore best avoided.

## Discussion

A simple Numba compatible re-implementation of [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) can be easily written:

```py
import random
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


@nb.njit
def random_sample_set(arr, k=-1):
    n = arr.size
    if k < 0:
        k = arr.size
    seen = {0}
    seen.clear()
    index = np.empty(k, dtype=arr.dtype)
    for i in range(k):
        j = random.randint(i, n - 1)
        while j in seen:
            j = random.randint(0, n - 1)
        seen.add(j)
        index[i] = j
    return arr[index]
```

This uses a temporary `set()` named `seen` which stores all the indices seen previously and avoids re-using them.

This should always be faster than `random.sample()`.

---

A potentially much faster version of this can be written by just shuffling (a portion of a copy of) the input:

```py
import random
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def random_sample_shuffle(arr, k=-1):
    n = arr.size
    if k < 0:
        k = arr.size
    result = arr.copy()
    for i in range(k):
        j = random.randint(i, n - 1)
        result[i], result[j] = result[j], result[i]
    return result[:k].copy()
```

This is faster than `random_sample_set()` as long as the `k` parameter is sufficiently large.
The larger the input array, the larger the `k` parameter needs to be to outperform `random_sample_set()`.
This is so because `random_sample_set()` will have a high collision rate of `j` in `seen`, causing the `while`-loop to run multiple times on average.

Also, this has a memory footprint independent of `k`, which is higher than that of `random_sample_set()`, whose memory footprint is proportional to `k`.

---

A slight variation of `random_sample_shuffle()` is `random_sample_shuffle_idx()` which uses indices instead of copying the input.
This would have a memory footprint independent of the data type, being more efficient for larger data types, and significantly faster for small values of `k` and typically on par (or slightly slower) in the general case:

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def random_sample_shuffle_idx(arr, k=-1):
    n = arr.size
    if k < 0:
        k = arr.size
    index = np.arange(n)
    for i in range(k):
        j = random.randint(i, n - 1)
        index[i], index[j] = index[j], index[i]
    return arr[index[:k]]
```

---

When comparing the above with [`np.random.choice(replace=False)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def random_sample_choice(arr, k=-1):
    if k < 0:
        k = arr.size
    return np.random.choice(arr, k, replace=False)
```

one would observe that this sits between `random_sample_set()` and `random_sample_shuffle()` when it comes to speed, as long as the input is sufficiently small and `k` is not too small.

Of course `np.random.choice()` and its newer counterpart [`random.Generator.choice()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) offer a lot more functionality than these simple implementations.

---

## Benchmarks

Some quick benchmarks can be generated with the following:

```py
funcs = random_sample_set, random_sample_shuffle


def is_good(x):
    return len(x) == len(set(x))


for q in range(4, 24, 4):
    n = 2 ** q
    arr = np.arange(n)
    seq = arr.tolist()
    for k in range(n // 8, n + 1, n // 8):
        print(f"n = {n}, k = {k}")
        func = random.sample
        print(f"{func.__name__:>24s} {is_good(func(seq, k))!s:>5s}", end=" ")
        %timeit -n 1 -r 1 func(seq, k)
        for func in funcs:
            print(f"{func.__name__:>24s} {is_good(func(arr, k))!s:>5s}", end=" ")
            %timeit -n 4 -r 4 func(arr, k)
```

The most interesting results are:

```
...
n = 65536, k = 65536
                        sample  True 41 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
             random_sample_set  True 22 ms ± 1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
         random_sample_shuffle  True 1 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
     random_sample_shuffle_idx  True 948 µs ± 94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
          random_sample_choice  True 918 µs ± 67.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
...
n = 1048576, k = 131072
                        sample  True 136 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
             random_sample_set  True 19 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
         random_sample_shuffle  True 5.85 ms ± 303 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
     random_sample_shuffle_idx  True 6.95 ms ± 445 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
          random_sample_choice  True 26.1 ms ± 1.93 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
...
n = 1048576, k = 917504
                        sample  True 916 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
             random_sample_set  True 313 ms ± 47.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
         random_sample_shuffle  True 29.4 ms ± 1.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
     random_sample_shuffle_idx  True 32.8 ms ± 1.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
          random_sample_choice  True 28.2 ms ± 1.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
...
```

And the *small `k` regime* (which is the use-case of the question):

```py
for q in range(4, 28, 4):
    n = 2 ** q
    arr = np.arange(n)
    seq = arr.tolist()
    k = 16
    print(f"n = {n}, k = {k}")
    func = random.sample
    print(f"{func.__name__:>24s} {is_good(func(seq, k))!s:>5s}", end=" ")
    %timeit -n 1 -r 1 func(seq, k)
    for func in funcs:
        print(f"{func.__name__:>24s} {is_good(func(arr, k))!s:>5s}", end=" ")
        %timeit -n 4 -r 4 func(arr, k)
```

```
n = 16, k = 16
                        sample  True 39.1 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
             random_sample_set  True 5.11 µs ± 2.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
         random_sample_shuffle  True 2.62 µs ± 1.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
     random_sample_shuffle_idx  True 2.51 µs ± 1.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
          random_sample_choice  True 2.39 µs ± 1.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
n = 256, k = 16
                        sample  True 43.7 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
             random_sample_set  True 3.67 µs ± 2.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
         random_sample_shuffle  True 2.59 µs ± 1.72 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
     random_sample_shuffle_idx  True The slowest run took 4.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
2.8 µs ± 2.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
          random_sample_choice  True 5.47 µs ± 1.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
n = 4096, k = 16
                        sample  True 33.4 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
             random_sample_set  True 3.53 µs ± 1.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
         random_sample_shuffle  True 4.2 µs ± 1.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
     random_sample_shuffle_idx  True 3.23 µs ± 1.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
          random_sample_choice  True 51.7 µs ± 4.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
n = 65536, k = 16
                        sample  True 58.9 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
             random_sample_set  True 4.15 µs ± 2.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
         random_sample_shuffle  True 35.3 µs ± 7.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
     random_sample_shuffle_idx  True 15.1 µs ± 5.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
          random_sample_choice  True The slowest run took 5.93 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
2.3 ms ± 1.61 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
n = 1048576, k = 16
                        sample  True 48.2 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
             random_sample_set  True 3.89 µs ± 2.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
         random_sample_shuffle  True 1.87 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
     random_sample_shuffle_idx  True 810 µs ± 195 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
          random_sample_choice  True 30.6 ms ± 2.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
n = 16777216, k = 16
                        sample  True 70.4 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
             random_sample_set  True 5.15 µs ± 3.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
         random_sample_shuffle  True 103 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
     random_sample_shuffle_idx  True 75.2 ms ± 3.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
          random_sample_choice  True 863 ms ± 77.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 4 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I did some time measurements, I want to show you the results (regarding my comments on your question)

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit
import numba as nb
import random

def func2():
    List = range(100000)
    for x in range(1000):
        random.sample(List, 10)

@nb.njit()
def func3():
    Array = np.arange(100000)
    for x in range(1000):
        np.random.choice(Array, 10, replace=False)

def func4():
    Array = np.arange(100000)
    for x in range(1000):
        np.random.choice(Array, 10, replace=False)

def func5():
    Array = np.arange(100000)
    for x in range(1000):
        np.random.default_rng().choice(Array, 10, replace=False)

print(f"random.sample {timeit(lambda: func2(), number=1)}")
print(f"np.random.choice JIT incl. compiling {timeit(lambda: func3(), number=1)}")
print(f"np.random.choice JIT excl. compiling {timeit(lambda: func3(), number=1)}")
print(f"np.random.choice {timeit(lambda: func4(), number=1)}")
print(f"np.random.default_rng.choice {timeit(lambda: func5(), number=1)}")
```

Giving you:

```
random.sample 0.0090606
np.random.choice JIT incl. compiling 1.9129443
np.random.choice JIT excl. compiling 0.8365084999999999
np.random.choice 1.8339632999999997
np.random.default_rng.choice 0.049018499999999854
```

Comment: I noticed that as well but if I'm not doing anything wrong, is there a way to improve the performance of my numba function?

Comment: I think it really depends on your real use case to optimize this..

Comment: If I dont use numba the remaining part of my code would be slow...

Comment: yes, so you're using `np.random.choice` for that exact problem as above? or is there something more?

Comment: Currently my code works differently but in principle beeing able to use np.random.choice / random.sample efficiently, should speed up my code significantly. I guess I will now take a look at how random.sample is coded and then check whether I can change that function to work with numba.