# Use entire list in pseudo-random number generation

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pseudo-Random Traversal of a Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765703/psuedo-random-traversal-of-a-set)

I'm trying to write an algorithm that will put the songs of a playlist into a random order, so if there are 10 songs, I need the random number generator to hit every value from 0-9 before repeating.  Using the algorithm: `x_current = (a * x_prev + c) mod m`,  is there any way to achieve this with certain values for a `c` and `m`?

Comment: Have you looked at std::random_shuffle? (And std::shuffle in C++11?)

Comment: What you want is not a list of random numbers, but to swap randomly-selected entries of a list of songs a certain number of times.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`std::random_shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/)

```
 vector<int> playOrder;    

  // set some values:
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) playOrder.push_back(i); // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

  // Don't forget to seed, or mix will be the same each run
  srand(time(NULL)); 

  // using built-in random generator:
  random_shuffle ( playOrder.begin(), playOrder.end() );

  // An example of how you might use the new random array.
  for(int i=0; i<playOrder.size(); i++)
    player.PlayTrack(playOrder[i]);
```

Comment: Or just std::shuffle, using an engine from `<random>`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765703/psuedo-random-traversal-of-a-set). Also, for small playlists, simply shuffling an array with the song numbers will be sufficient.

Comment: "Simply shuffling an array" is the problem description.

Comment: Traversing a set in random order without repetition is the problem description. Shuffling an array would be a possible solution.

Comment: You are correct; I am simply suggesting that you may need to progress slightly further from the problem description in order for the OP to recognise it as a possible solution. :) His proposed "algorithm" is already intended to essentially shuffle an array and he is trying to find a different way to do it.