# A randomized array with no repeating values

Tags: java, arrays

i need an array contains 10 elements with no repeating integers.. so my question is how to make an if condition to check everytime if the next random value is in the array or not..
i need a simple code i'm just a beginner 
here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []a = new int [10];

    for (int i =0 ; i< 10 ; i++)
    { 
        a[i]= (int)(Math.random()*100)+1;
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158716/how-do-you-efficiently-generate-a-list-of-k-non-repeating-integers-between-0-and

Comment: I believe the OP is a beginner of sorts. Incase you need help @Samihanna here's the code you're looking for: http://ideone.com/mmSojn

Comment: You can use a hashset to store numbers. A set only stores unique entities. Keep adding stuff until the limit '10' is reached, and finally convert this to an array and you're done.

Comment: If you're just beginning, here's the algorithm I would use: before inserting the number at i, check the values of the array from 0 to i-1. If any of them match the number you want to insert, generate a new random number and repeat the process. This isn't the most efficient way of doing it, but its a good learning experience. Look up while loops and break statements.

Comment: `int[] a ={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; java.util.Arrays.shuffle(a);` The values are not random, but their position yes.