# How to generate non repeating random numbers in ios?

Tags: ios, random, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non repeating random numbers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617630/non-repeating-random-numbers)

How to generate non repeating random numbers?

I saw this on many sites but they give in main.c file code.

When I use the main.c file the code working is fine, but when I try to convert in to my.m file it is not working.

example:

I need to get all the numbers between 0-10 randomly.and the numbers should not repeat again.

Comment: There is no such thing.  Any computer generated random number will be a repeating sequence.

Comment: There are what are called "cryptographically secure" random numbers.  They gain entropy continually from many events on the computer.  For all intents they are random.  The access function is arc4random().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arc4random()
Example:

```
- (NSData *)randomBytes:(size_t)count
{
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:count];

    SecRandomCopyBytes( kSecRandomDefault,
                        data.length,
                        data.mutableBytes);
    return data;
}
```

It turns out that getting a random number in a range is not as simple as using mod.

```
- (u_int32_t)randomInRangeLo:(u_int32_t)loBound toHi:(u_int32_t)hiBound
{
    u_int32_t random;
    int32_t   range = hiBound - loBound + 1;
    u_int32_t limit = UINT32_MAX - (UINT32_MAX % range);

    do {
        random = arc4random();
    } while (random > limit);

    return loBound + (random % range);
}
```

Comment: Well there is a way: if you number has to be between 10 and 50: `random = (arc4random()%40) + 10;`

Comment: Yes,that will provide a number in a range but it is biased by the way it is restricted (mod).  You will see this done a lot but it is wrong.  Getting cryptography correct is hard.

Comment: but i want every single number between that range to be displayed

Comment: Every number in the range will be displayed without bias, that is the point. Using mod (%) will create results that have a bias (toward lower numbers), the bias may be small and the bias may not be important in most usages.  Make a choice but understand what you are choosing.

Answer (score 1):

CocoaFu provides excellent random numbers. What you're asking for is a shuffle. The easiest is a Fischer-Yates shuffle. There are several good versions provided in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). You can also read about the modulo bias that CocoaFu's algorithm avoids.

But there is absolutely no reason a C implementation will not work precisely the same in Objective-C. If you've had problems moving from a `.c` file to a `.m` file, you should post your errors.