# How to generate random numbers from 1-99 range in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

This is my code for generating random numbers from 1-99, but it's only generating same set of numbers (15 numbers) every time. I'm storing those numbers in an `NSArray` and getting output in `NSLog` properly. It's ok, but I want different set of random numbers with no repeated number whenever I call this random method. Can any one help me please?

```
-(void) randoms
{

    myset=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    int D[20];
    BOOL flag;
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        int randum= random()%100;
        flag= true;
        int size= (sizeof D);

        for (int x=0; x<size; x++)
        {
            if (randum == D[x])
            {
                i--;
                flag= false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag) D[i]=randum;

    }
    for (int j=0; j<15; j++)
        {
        myset=[myset arrayByAddingObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:D[j]]];
        }

    NSLog(@"first set..%@",myset.description);
}
```

Comment: Give this one a try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c

Comment: That was seriously annoying. Did a nice long answer with code that has great explanation in it and this question got closed. I will add it to a blog and provide you with a link when I can.

Comment: While there is an element that is a duplicate - generating unique random numbers, there is also the element of putting the random numbers in a set, so I have nominated to reopen

Comment: @Paulw11 There are many SO questions asking this.  [Take your pick](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+random+always+the+same)

Comment: @JeremyP I agree that the random seeding is a duplicate, but not the creating a set of unique random numbers within bounds.

Comment: @Paulw11 Plenty of questions about [non repeating random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+random+non+repeating) too.

Comment: @Popeye: "Did a nice long answer with code that has great explanation in it and this question got closed." Why did you vote to close then?

Comment: I voted to close first then realized I was wrong. Have since voted to reopen

Comment: It's possible to retract an already-cast vote, @Popeye, if you change your mind before the question is closed. This is a recent-ish feature.

Answer (score 2):

You have to seed the generator before using it. If you want to skip the seeding, you can use **arc4random_uniform()**. It's a different algorithm and takes care of the seeding process on its own. Other than that, you can use it in your code almost exactly like you used **random()**. You'll just have to specify the upper bound as a parameter, instead of using modulo:

```
-(void) randoms
{

    myset=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    int D[20];
    BOOL flag;
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        int randum= arc4random_uniform(100);
        flag= true;
        int size= (sizeof D);

        for (int x=0; x<size; x++)
        {
            if (randum == D[x])
            {
                i--;
                flag= false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag) D[i]=randum;

    }
    for (int j=0; j<15; j++)
        {
        myset=[myset arrayByAddingObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:D[j]]];
        }

    NSLog(@"first set..%@",myset.description);
}
```

Comment: [arc4random_uniform()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7082580/169346) is the way to go

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of arc4random_uniform(). Edited the answer, and I'll probably use it in the future instead of arc4random().

Comment: yeah,,, great great work done by you.. brilliant assistance to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command before starting your arc4random

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410571/non-repeating-random-numbers-in-iphone   try above link...

Comment: Do you even know what that does? If so please add an explanation of what it is and does, for those that don't

Comment: It seeds the pseudo random number generator that rand() uses..  for more detail check this link:- 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want a set containing 15 random numbers between 1-99.  You can use the following:

```
- (NSSet *)randomSetOfSize:(int)size lowerBound:(int)lowerBound upperBound:(int)upperBound {
    NSMutableSet *randomSet=[NSMutableSet new];
    while (randomSet.count <size) {
        int randomInt=arc4random_uniform(upperBound-lowerBound)+lowerBound;
        NSNumber *randomNumber=[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomInt];
        [randomSet addObject:randomNumber];
    }

    return randomSet;
}
```

and call it with

```
NSSet *myRandomSet=[self randomSetOfSize:14 lowerBound:1 upperBound:99];
```