# Want to generate non repeating random numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating non-repeating random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554292/generating-non-repeating-random-numbers)

Here is my code

```
NSUInteger count = 10;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    NSLog(@"%d",NeedRandomNumberWithoutRepeat);
}
```

this output should be like
8
7
9
2
1
4
6
3
5
0
Which is random and not repeating numbers

Comment: What you want? id total numbers are 10, you need to generate random number 1 to 10, only once? What for 11th time?

Comment: not problem with generate random number, Problem with repeating number

Comment: You probably want a "random permutation" of N numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554292/generating-non-repeating-random-numbers contains links to algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
NSUInteger count = 10;

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}

NSMutableArray *copy = [array mutableCopy];
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
while ([copy count] > 0)
{
    int index = arc4random() % [copy count];
    id objectToMove = [copy objectAtIndex:index];
    [array addObject:objectToMove];
    [copy removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: I tried but still number generate with repetation

Comment: The code I posted gives random numbers that are different every time.

Comment: I tried your code but, number generate like num == 3 and again num == 3

Comment: The code is correct, the problem is % count. That puts the arc4random result in a range between 0 and 9 and in this small range you have collisions. Maybe @sachin can explain what he wants to do so we can help him with the problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now you get an array with 10 numbers in random order.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is modified version from one of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640208/how-to-generate-non-repeating-random-number-objective-c/13640257#13640257) in SO.

So, you may find something strange here, you can however use this as your requirement is similar.

```
int TOTAL_NUMBER=10;
NSMutableArray *alreadyGeneratedNumbers;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    alreadyGeneratedNumbers=[NSMutableArray new];
}

-(int)generateRandomNumber{
    int low_bound = 0;
    int high_bound = TOTAL_NUMBER;
    int width = high_bound - low_bound;
    int randomNumber = low_bound + arc4random() % width;

    return randomNumber;
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *shuffle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    BOOL contains=YES;
    while ([shuffle count]<1) {
        NSNumber *generatedNumber=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[self generateRandomNumber]];

        if (![alreadyGeneratedNumbers containsObject:generatedNumber]) {
            [shuffle addObject:generatedNumber];
            contains=NO;
            [alreadyGeneratedNumbers addObject:generatedNumber];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"shuffle %@",shuffle);
    NSLog(@"Next Batch");

    if ([alreadyGeneratedNumbers count] >= TOTAL_NUMBER) {
        NSLog(@"\nGame over, Want to play once again?");//or similar kind of thing.
        [alreadyGeneratedNumbers removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You put the available numbers in an array, and take the index calculated with arc4random() that goes from 0 to the size of the array -1.When a number comes out you take it away from the array:

```
NSMutableArray* availableNumbers=[NSMutableArray new];
for(NSUInteger i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    [availableNumbers addObject: @(i)];
}
for(NSUInteger i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    NSUInteger index= arc4random()%availableNumbers.count;
    NSNumber* number= availableNumbers[index];
    NSLog(@"%@",number);
    [availableNumbers removeObjectAtIndex: index];
}
```

PS: At the last iteration is useless to sue arc4random(), since there's only one number inside.