# Random numbers no repeat loop generator on xcode

Tags: objective-c, arc4random

I know it's newbie question but I really need some help. I am trying to create a while loop with an `integer` temporary array on `Xcode` for four numbers. On every loop I want to check the previous number and store it to my table until that fills the four numbers.The numbers that I want to randomize are between `2-5`. 
So here is my thought for the start:

```
ans= arc4random()%4+2;

            seq[]=ans;
            counter=+1
            while (uniq==true) {
                ans=arc4random()%4+2;
            }
            Uniq=true
            for(int i=0; I <4; i++)
            If (ans=seq[i]){
            Uniq==false

            Seq[counter=ans]
                Counter++}
```

I know that i am missing things. If someone can help me i will be gratefull

Comment: 2,3,4,5 is the list from where you want random picks?

Comment: Yes, that's why i start with ans= arc4random()%4+2; and then i want to check the first result and then continue with next number of these numbers until it fill the whole array.

Comment: @user2437643 What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  If you want the numbers 2-5 in a random order, it would be much more efficient to shuffle them.

Comment: I am trying to create random pick of 2-5 numbers and finally to have an array let say as example seq=[3,5,2,4]. And i need this result to put it on 4 labels that i created.

Comment: Just throw them in a NSMutableArray and shuffle them using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/1445366

Comment: I can't believe no one has marked this dupe yet -- this question comes up about once every two weeks.

Comment: Sorry, @HotLicks, I've been elsewhere. :) Possible duplicate of [Non-repeating random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1617630), and [a veritable host of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjc%5D+non-repeating+random+numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: (**Not compile checked*)

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"]];
NSMutableArray *mArray = [NSMutableArray new];

while (array.count > 0) {
    NSUInteger index = arc4random() % array.count;
    mArray[mArray.count] = array[index];
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: Corrected the obvious errors, not sure if you can add items with `[]` since I don't use it.

Comment: @Sulthan: you can add :) if the index is out of bound a new one gets added. `mArray[mArray.count]` was I wanted to use. even your edit is good, same thing :).

Comment: Oh, sorry. The `.` was missing so I just chose one solution :)

Comment: Thank you for this response. And from this mArray how can i pull out the random series on labels? On my previus code i used standard the numbers like this. answer1.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 3)];

Comment: @user2437643: marray contains the random series, you can get values from this array.