# Generate N quasi random numbers in less than O(N)

Tags: algorithm, random

This was inspired by a question at a job interview: how do you efficiently generate N unique random numbers? Their security and distribution/bias don't matter.

I proposed a naive way of calling rand() N times and eliminating dupes by trial and error, thus getting inefficient and flawed solution. Then I've read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608181/unique-random-numbers-in-an-integer-array-in-the-c-programming-language), these algorithms are great for getting quality unique numbers and they are O(N).

But I suspect there are ways to get low-quality unique random numbers for dummy tasks in less than O(N) time complexity. I got some possible ideas:

- Store many precomputed lists each containing N numbers and retrieve one list randomly. Complexity is O(1) for fixed N. Storage space used is O(NR) where R is number of lists.
- Generate N/2 unique random numbers and then divide them by 2 inequal parts (floor/ceil for odd numbers, n+1/n-1 for even). I know this is flawed (duplicates can pop up) and O(N/2) is still O(N). This is more of a food for thought.
- Generate one big random number and then squeeze more variants from it by some fixed manipulations like bitwise operations, factorization, recursion, MapReduce or something else.
- Use a [quasi-random sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) somehow (not a math guy, just googled this term).

Your ideas?

Comment: Was their complaint that your solution's big-O complexity was too high, or just that it was too inefficient? Because there are more efficient ways to generate _unique_ numbers in a given range than trial and error. Also, your solution isn't O(n) worst case - to generate a random permutation of n from n, it'll run in O(n^2) time due to the number of retries required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably this routine has some kind of output (i.e. the results are written to an array of some kind).  Populating an array (or some other data-structure) of size N is at least an O(N) operation, so you can't do better than O(N).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I modified a question accordingly.

Comment: @pati- You are probably better off accepting Oli's answer, then posting a second question.  That way, anyone searching for your original question can get it answered directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can consequently generate a random number, and if the result array contains it, just add to it the maximum number of already generated numbers.

Detecting if a number already generated is O(1) (using a hash set). So it's O(n) and with only N `random()` calls.

Of course, this is an assumption that we do not overflow the upper limit (i.e. BigInteger).

Comment: Yep, that's nice and simple O(N) solution similar to [Floyd algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1608585/1320363) but with less 'math-proven distribution quality', I guess.

Comment: The distribution is not a concern from your question: "Their security and distribution/bias don't matter."