# Insert a list of numbers randomly into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a list of numbers between 1-20,000. I wish to insert all of these numbers *randomly* into a table and only once. How can I accomplish this?

For example with 1-10, they would be inserted in the below order, not 1, 2 , 3, 4

9
3
5
1
2
4
6
..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

```
$arr = <numbers 1-20K>

shuffle($arr);

<code to insert into sql>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Knuths or Floyds algorithm to achieve this and then store all the numbers in the database. Read this SO question for both the implementation:

[Unique random numbers in an integer array in the C programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608181/unique-random-numbers-in-an-integer-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

One tip, make sure you dont save into the database for every number generated, you should batch your inserts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was going to insert one by one. What is the limit on the amount you can insert in a batch?

Comment: the max number of inserts depends on the setting of the 
MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET variable. If you create a packet that is too large 
exceeding this value you will run into problems