# 50 random unique elements from an array of 1000 elemens?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

What is the simplest way to get 50 random unique elements from an array of 1000 elements ?

```
text = new Array();
for(i=0;i<1000;i++){ text[i]=i; }   //array populated
// now I need to get 50 random unique elements from this array.
```

Comment: What do you mean by unique elements? You mean unique indexes or unique values in the indexes?

Answer (score 4):

The obvious (to me) way is to shuffle the array, then take the first fifty elements.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array) has a good way to shuffle an array, and you can then [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the first fifty elements. This guarantees the elements will be unique.

So, using the function there:

```
fisherYates(text);
text = text.slice(0, 50);
```

Comment: Nice idea! However, it will work only if that 1000 elements are unique.

Comment: @VisioN In that case, ensure that the elements in `text` are unique. There are plenty of functions available to do precisely this, such as [this one](http://www.jslab.dk/library/Array.unique).

Comment: VisioN is right, also it is expensive to shuffle a 1000 len array

Comment: run the shuffle algorithm for only 50 cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Good algorithms explained in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608181/unique-random-numbers-in-an-integer-array-in-the-c-programming-language) (in C but you can easily to do same in JS)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), I think this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you meant unique values:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vZTXE/3/)**

```
var old_arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], new_array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var rand_elem = old_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * old_arr.length)];

    if (arrIndex(old_arr[rand_elem], new_array) == -1) {
        new_array.push(rand_elem);
    } else {
        i--;
    }
}

function arrIndex(to_find, arr) {//own function for IE support
    if (Array.prototype.indexOf) {
        return arr.indexOf(to_find);
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in arr && arr[i] === to_find) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

In case you meant unique indexs:

- Generate random indexes and store the indexes in an array and make checks to prevent duplicates
- Start removing the elements of the array after you get them, (you might have problems if you cache the length, so don't)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
while(arr.length < 51){
    var ind = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    if(!(ind in arr))
        arr.push(ind)
}
```

You'll have 50 random unique numbers in the array arr, which you could use as index

EDIT:

As @ajax333221 mentioned, the previous code doesn't do to get unique elements from the array, in case it contains duplicates. So this is the fix:

```
var result_arr = [];
while(result_arr.length < 51){
    var ind = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    if(text[ind] && !(text[ind] in result_arr))
        result_arr.push(text[ind]);
}
```

Being 'text' the array populated with 1000 values

Comment: -1 a) that don't generate unique numbers correctly, b)even if you fix it, unique numbers are useless if the 1k array contain duplicates

Comment: Yep you are right, I misunderstood the question, I just thought about getting 50 unique index numbers. Why do you say it doesn't generate the unique numbers correctly??

Comment: @d because `if(!(ind in arr))` is not the correct check to do, it checks if the index is contained in the array (not a value). So if you add 23 in the first loop, the 23 will be possible to duplicate the next 22 loops. You might want to use indexOf instead

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you mean random indexes and not indexes with unique values.

One way is to copy the array and prune off the ones you use:

```
function getRandomIndexes( arr, cnt){
    var randomArr = [],
        arrCopy = arr.slice(),
        i, 
        randomNum ;
    for (i=0;i<arrCopy.length;i++) {
        randomNum = Math.floor( arrCopy.length * Math.random());
        randomArr = randomArr.concat(  arrCopy.splice(randomNum ,1) );
    }    
    return randomArr;
}

var myNums = [], i, randSet;
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    myNums.push(i);
}
randSet = getRandomIndexes(myNums, 5);
```

Another way is to keep track of the indexes you use and keep looking until you find one you did not use. I find the while loop to be scary, and personally would not use this solution if random indexes needed approaches close to the array length.

```
function getRandomIndexes( arr, cnt){
    var randomArr = [],
        usedNums = {},
        x;
    while (randomArr.length<cnt) {
        while (usedNums[x]===true || x===undefined) {
            x = Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length);
        }
        usedNums[x] = true;
        randomArr.push( arr[x] );
    }
    return randomArr;
}

var myNums = [], i, randSet;
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
    myNums.push(i);
}
randSet = getRandomIndexes(myNums, 5);
```

Comment: interesting, first time I see `arr.slice()` (I always see `arr.slice(0)`), but I guess it should work too

Answer (score -2):

Math.random() * 1000;

Generate 50 random numbers and use them as the position in the array.

Comment: I'm doing some assuming here.  I'm assuming you are checking your random values, just like I'm assuming you know how to store those fifty numbers without me showing you  :)