# Objective-C: Randomly replace characters in string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I'd like to have a function that removes a random set of characters from a string and replaces them with '_'. eg. to create a fill in the blanks type of situation. The way I have it now works, but its not smart. Also I don't want to replace spaces with blanks (as you can see in the while loop). Any suggestions on a more efficient way to do this?

```
blankItem = @"Remove Some Characters";
for(int j=0;j<totalRemove;j++)
{
    replaceLocation=arc4random() % blankItem.length;
    while ([blankItem characterAtIndex:replaceLocation] == '_' || [blankItem characterAtIndex:replaceLocation] == ' ') {
         replaceLocation=arc4random() % blankItem.length;
    }
   blankItem= [blankItem stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(replaceLocation, 1) withString:@"_"];
}
```

**My issue is with the for and while loops in terms of efficiency. But, maybe efficiency isn't of the essence in something this small?**

Comment: `blankItem= (NSMutableString *)[blankItem …` seems to show you believe casting magically changes the object's class. Fortunately you don't really use the fact that `blankItem` is a mutable string since you are allocating a new string at each iteration.

Comment: `replaceLocation=arc4random() % blankItem.length;` -> `replaceLocation = arc4random_uniform(blankItem.length);`

Comment: Warning, a string of only _ and spaces will result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of characters to remove/replace is small compared to the length of the
string, then your solution is good, because the probability of a "collision" in the
while-loop is small. You can improve the method by using a single mutable string instead of
allocating a new string in each step:

```
NSString *string = @"Remove Some Characters";
int totalRemove = 5;

NSMutableString *result = [string mutableCopy];
for (int j=0; j < totalRemove; j++) {
    int replaceLocation;
    do {
        replaceLocation = arc4random_uniform((int)[result length]);
    } while ([result characterAtIndex:replaceLocation] == '_' || [result characterAtIndex:replaceLocation] == ' ');
    [result replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(replaceLocation, 1) withString:@"_"];
}
```

---

If the number of characters to remove/replace is about the same magnitude as the
length of the string, then a different algorithm might be better.

The following code uses the ideas from [Unique random numbers in an integer array in the C programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608181/unique-random-numbers-in-an-integer-array-in-the-c-programming-language) to replace characters
at random positions with a single loop over all characters of the string.

An additional (first) pass is necessary because of your requirement that space characters
are not replaced.

```
NSString *string = @"Remove Some Characters";
int totalRemove = 5;

// First pass: Determine number of non-space characters:
__block int count = 0;
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                              options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                           usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    if (![substring isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        count++;
    }
}];

// Second pass: Replace characters at random positions:
__block int c = count; // Number of remaining non-space characters
__block int r = totalRemove; // Number of remaining characters to replace
NSMutableString *result = [string mutableCopy];
[result enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [result length])
                              options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                           usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
   if (![substring isEqualToString:@" "]) {
       // Replace this character with probability r/c:
       if (arc4random_uniform(c) < r) {
           [result replaceCharactersInRange:substringRange withString:@"_"];
           r--;
           if (r == 0) *stop = YES; // Stop enumeration, nothing more to do.
       }
       c--;
   }
}];
```

Another advantage of this solution is that it handles surrogate pairs (e.g. Emojis) and composed character sequences correctly, even if these are stores as *two separate* characters in the string.