# Assign unique random integers in an array (C)

Tags: c, arrays, random, unique

im struggling with this so long, i can fill my array with random numbers
but they are not unique. I can't spot the problem in my code :( Can you help me? Thanks

```
int getUniqueNumber(int *p, int i)
{
    int x,j,found;
    do
    {
        x=rand()%100000 + 1;
        found=0;
        j=0;
        while(j<=i && found==0)
        {
            if(p[i]==x)
                found=1;
            else
                j++;
        }
    } while(found==1);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: "*...they are not unique*" in which sense?

Comment: Well if i printf the first 10 elements here's what i get:
5
6
7
10
11
11
12
12
13
14

there are same numbers in the array..

Comment: You should read [Unique random numbers in an integer array in the C programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608181/unique-random-numbers-in-an-integer-array-in-the-c-programming-language) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p[i] == x` should be `p[j] == x`.

Comment: oh lord.. i can't believe i coudn't see that mistake all this time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The function can be defined the following way

```
int getUniqueNumber( const int *p, int i )
{
    int x, j;

    do
    {
        x = rand() % 100000 + 1;

        j = 0;
        while ( j < i && p[j] != x ) ++j;
    } while( j != i );

    return x;
}
```

As for your function implementation then there are a wrong condition in the loop (j <= i )

```
    while(j<=i && found==0)
```

and incorrect using of index i instead of index j

```
        if(p[i]==x)
```