# how to grab a "random" set of items from a loop in php

Tags: php

Im looping through some XML nodes, and say i have between 1 and 200 of these nodes.

How can i "randomly" select a maximum of 10 of these nodes. It has to be as most ten, but as few as 1.

This is what im working with now...

```
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($butters->users->user as $user) {
            if($i==10) break;
            $id = $user->id;
            $name = $user->screen_name;
            $profimg = $user->profile_image_url;
            echo "things";
            $i++;
        }
```

The difficulty is that i don't know how many i will have, but would like the pool from which i select my "random" 10 to be from the entirety of however many are present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$randomPool = array_rand ( $butters->users->user, 10 );
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, depending on what XML module he is using, as array_rand requires array as first item, however $butters->users->user maybe a DOMNODE::ELEMENT_LIST if you are using the DOM module.

Could be wrong though

Comment: What works on foreach will work on array_rand() too,
assuming Patrick's given example didn't output an error.

Comment: It sounds as if the patrick wants 10 as an upper limit on the random elements so you should be passing a random number between 1 and 10 for the second argument of array_rand then you will get a random set of nodes with a length between 1 and 10

Answer (score 3):

I'd get the 10 random indexes, then loop through those and get the nodes.

```
$indexes = array();
for($i = 0; $i< 10; $i++){
  $indexes[] = rand(0, $butters->users->length);
}

foreach($indexes as $index){
  $user = $butters->users->item($index);
  //do whatever with $user
}
```

You'll need to add a check to make sure that you have not already got the index when you add it to the $indexes array.

You could put this into one command, however you may end up with duplicates (unlikely depending on the amount of elements, but possible...

```
for($i = 0; $i< 10; $i++){
  $user = $butters->users->item(rand(0, $butters->users->length));
  //do something with $user
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put all users in an array, shuffle it and grab the first ten items:

```
$users = array[];
foreach ($butters->users->user as $user) {
    $users[] = &$user;
}
shuffle($users);
$tenRandomUsers = array_slice($users, 0, 10);
```

Maybe you can shorten the first step with just `$users = (array) $butters->users->user`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a random object (don't know the PHP specific code) then call it and compare with 10 / (total in the set).  This means you should in theory select 10%, however it could be less, and your exiting code stops it from selecting more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SimpleXML, you could use an [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to get all the users. This will return an array and from that it should be cake.

Something like this should do:

```
$users  = $xml->xpath('//butters/users/user');
$random = array_rand($users, 10);
```

*Someone might want to correct me on the Xpath though. Doing it from memory*

Answer (score 0):

if you have some sort of strange self-implemented data structure for $users you might want to use reservior sampling -- [Efficiently selecting a set of random elements from a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059/efficiently-selecting-a-set-of-random-elements-from-a-linked-list)