# Given a list of length n select k random elements using C#

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I found this post:

[Efficiently selecting a set of random elements from a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059/efficiently-selecting-a-set-of-random-elements-from-a-linked-list)

But this means that in order to approach true randomness in the sample I have to iterate over all elements, throw them in memory with a random number, and then sort.  I have a very large set of items here (millions) - is there a more efficient approach to this problem?

Comment: Using a c# list is different than using a linked list as described in the link.

Comment: We need more information. Do you already have the elements in memory, in a mutable collection? Do you also need to preserve the original order?

Comment: Depending on the already requested information, your best approach may be to do a partial [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), stopping after `k` iterations.

Comment: Are you looking for elements at unique indexes? Are you looking for unique element values? Do you need elements sorted by value or sorted by their indexes?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I'm working with LINQ so I think that means they can be in memory if needed.  They are in a Queryable DbSet.  I do not need to preserve the original order - I would prefer not to, in the name of randomness.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - I need any random unique selection of k elements - no duplicates, and no sorting.

Comment: @DanTeesdale - right - I'm dealing with a C# DbSet currently in List form but can be any LINQ-friendly collection type

Comment: You don't have to load them all into a collection. See [Random selection from large groups](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=796).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I read your comment here after writing my answer. Great mind think alike ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest simply shuffling elements as if you were writing a modified Fisher-Yates shuffle, but only bother shuffling the first `k` elements. For example:

```
public static void PartialShuffle<T>(IList<T> source, int count, Random random)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // Pick a random element out of the remaining elements,
        // and swap it into place.
        int index = i + random.Next(source.Count - i);
        T tmp = source[index];
        source[index] = source[i];
        source[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

After calling this method, the first `count` elements will be randomly picked elements from the original list.

Note that I've specified the `Random` as a parameter, so that you can use the same one repeatedly. Be careful about threading though - see my [article on randomness](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this algorithm for a list with weighted probability?

Comment: @Iravanchi: You'd want to sum all the weights, so that when you pick a random number you can work out which value that corresponds to... but then when swapping the values, you'd need to swap the weights too. I think it would be hard to do very efficiently (you couldn't easily just use a cumulative list of weights, which would make it easy to find the corresponding value - updating the cumulative list would be a pain) but the rest would be okay.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this extension method http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/shuffle. You could add Skip() Take() type to page the values out the final list.

Answer (score 3):

If the elements can be in memory, put them in memory first

```
List<Element> elements = dbContext.Select<Element>();
```

Now you know the number of elements. Create a set of unique indexes.

```
var random = new Random();
var indexes = new HashSet<int>();
while (indexes.Count < k) {
    indexes.Add(random.Next(elements.Count));
}
```

Now you can read the elements from the list

```
var randomElements = indexes.Select(i => elements[i]);
```

I assume that the DB contains unique elements. If this is not the case, you will have to create a `HashSet<Elements>` instead or to append `.Distinct()` when querying from the DB.

---

**UPDATE**

As Patricia Shanahan says, this method will work well if k is small compared to n. If it is not the case, I suggest selecting a set n - k indexes to be excluded

```
var random = new Random();
var indexes = new HashSet<int>();
IEnumerable<Element> randomElements;

if (k <= elements.Count / 2) {
    while (indexes.Count < k) {
        indexes.Add(random.Next(elements.Count));
    }
    randomElements = indexes.Select(i => elements[i]);
} else {
    while (indexes.Count < elements.Count - k) {
        indexes.Add(random.Next(elements.Count));
    }
    randomElements = elements
        .Select((e,i) => indexes.Contains(i) ? null : elements[i])
        .Where(e => e != null);
}
```

Comment: This method will work well if k is small compared to n, so that repeat selections of the same element are rare. It may do a lot of iterations if k is close to n.

Comment: As Patricia says, this is not a good approach. It would be better to do a partial shuffle - see my answer for sample code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: If k is close to n you can select n-k random indexes to be excluded.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: That's true - but at that point it's both more complicated *and* less efficient than the partial shuffle.