# Count Min Sketch: How to handle counters overflow?

Tags: algorithm, count-min-sketch

So the whole point of [Count-Min Sketch](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~graham/pubs/papers/cmsoft.pdf) is to update certain counters depending on the results of the provided hash functions. But, these counters are limited in memory, and after running for quite some time, they might overflow, dropping from the MAX value to the MIN value (like Integers do). Assuming all I need is the N most frequent values in the sketch, is there a way to avoid this other than restarting the sketch every once in a while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an appropriately sized integer if this worries you.

An 8-byte (long long) unsigned integer has a maximum value of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. That should probably be enough.

**Edit**

> Assuming all I need is the N most frequent values in the sketch, is there a way to avoid this other than restarting the sketch every once in a while?

Perhaps you could adapt [reservoir sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21201378/752843) to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but let's assume I have very limited memory - is there another method?

Comment: Edited my answer: reservoir sampling might do what you want. But an extra byte or two would give you an elegant, simple solution; you'd have to be very byte-strapped to ignore that possibility.

Comment: The link you posted refers to a question about random sampling - I need the most frequent, unless I'm missing something here

Comment: @shakedzy: The most frequent items are most likely to appear in that sample. Given the number of items seen and the number of distinct items in the set, you could figure out the probability of an item appearing in that sample.